# How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator

I have two iterables, and I want to go over them in pairs:

```py
foo = [1, 2, 3]
bar = [4, 5, 6]

for (f, b) in iterate_together(foo, bar):
    print("f:", f, " |  b:", b)
```

That should result in:

```
f: 1  |  b: 4
f: 2  |  b: 5
f: 3  |  b: 6
```

*One* way to do it is to iterate over the indices:

```py
for i in range(len(foo)):
    print("f:", foo[i], " |  b:", bar[i])
```

But that seems somewhat unpythonic to me. Is there a better way to do it?

---

<sub>Related tasks:</sub>
<sub>* [How to merge lists into a list of tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407398/) - given the above `foo` and `bar`, create the list `[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]`.</sub>
<sub>* [How can I make a dictionary (dict) from separate lists of keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840) - create the dict `{1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}`.</sub>
<sub>* [Create a dictionary with comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747817) - constructing `dict` using `zip` in a dict comprehension.</sub>

Answer (score 1960, accepted):

### Python 3

```
for f, b in zip(foo, bar):
    print(f, b)
```

`zip` stops when the shorter of `foo` or `bar` stops.

In **Python 3**, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
returns an iterator of tuples, like `itertools.izip` in Python2.  To get a list
of tuples, use `list(zip(foo, bar))`. And to zip until both iterators are
exhausted, you would use
[itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

### Python 2

In **Python 2**, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)
returns a list of tuples. This is fine when `foo` and `bar` are not massive. If they are both massive then forming `zip(foo,bar)` is an unnecessarily massive
temporary variable, and should be replaced by `itertools.izip` or
`itertools.izip_longest`, which returns an iterator instead of a list.

```
import itertools
for f,b in itertools.izip(foo,bar):
    print(f,b)
for f,b in itertools.izip_longest(foo,bar):
    print(f,b)
```

`izip` stops when either `foo` or `bar` is exhausted.
`izip_longest` stops when both `foo` and `bar` are exhausted.
When the shorter iterator(s) are exhausted, `izip_longest` yields a tuple with `None` in the position corresponding to that iterator. You can also set a different `fillvalue` besides `None` if you wish. See here for the [full story](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

---

Note also that `zip` and its `zip`-like brethen can accept an arbitrary number of iterables as arguments. For example,

```
for num, cheese, color in zip([1,2,3], ['manchego', 'stilton', 'brie'], 
                              ['red', 'blue', 'green']):
    print('{} {} {}'.format(num, color, cheese))
```

prints

```
1 red manchego
2 blue stilton
3 green brie
```

Comment: Usually in Python, simpler is faster.  In CPython, `zip`'s for-loop and
item-getting is implemented in C. In contrast, `[(x[i], y[i]) for i in
range(...)]` uses a Python-level for-loop and each `x[i]` or `y[i]` requires a
Python-level call to `__getitem__`.  Generally, C-loops beat Python loops and
fewer function calls is faster than more function calls.  So intuition points to
`zip` being faster than indexing.

Comment: Of course, blanket statements about performance are foolish. So it's good to get
familiar with timeit and test things for yourself.  A little [timeit
test](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8220801/190597) on my machine confirms
`list(zip(x,y))` is about 3x faster than `[(x[i], y[i]) for i in
range(1000)]` for `x = y = list(range(1000))`.

Comment: urr...doesn't zip need the lists to be equal?

Comment: @AbhishekRai only with `strict=True`

Answer (score 97):

You want the `zip` function.

```
for (f,b) in zip(foo, bar):
    print "f: ", f ,"; b: ", b
```

Answer (score 24):

Building on the answer by [@unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1663826/5722359), I have compared the iteration performance of two identical lists when using Python 3.6's `zip()` functions, Python's `enumerate()` function, using a manual counter (see `count()` function), using an index-list, and during a special scenario where the elements of one of the two lists (either `foo` or `bar`) may be used to index the other list. Their performances for printing and creating a new list, respectively, were investigated using the `timeit()` function where the number of repetitions used was 1000 times. One of the Python scripts that I had created to perform these investigations is given below. The sizes of the `foo` and `bar` lists had ranged from 10 to 1,000,000 elements.

## Results:

1. **For printing purposes:** The performances of all the considered approaches were observed to be approximately similar to the `zip()` function, after factoring an accuracy tolerance of +/-5%. An exception occurred when the list size was smaller than 100 elements. In such a scenario, the index-list method was slightly slower than the `zip()` function while the `enumerate()` function was ~9% faster. The other methods yielded similar performance to the `zip()` function.

   [image: Print loop 1000 reps]
2. **For creating lists:** Two types of list creation approaches were explored: using the (a) `list.append()` method and (b) **list comprehension**. After factoring an accuracy tolerance of +/-5%, for both of these approaches, the `zip()` function was found to perform faster than the `enumerate()` function, than using a list-index, than using a manual counter. The performance gain by the `zip()` function in these comparisons can be 5% to 60% faster. Interestingly, using the element of `foo` to index `bar` can yield equivalent or faster performances (5% to 20%) than the `zip()` function.

   [image: Creating List - 1000reps]

## Making sense of these results:

A programmer has to determine the amount of compute-time per operation that is meaningful or that is of significance.

For example, for printing purposes, if this time criterion is 1 second, i.e. 10**0 sec, then looking at the y-axis of the graph that is on the left at 1 sec and projecting it horizontally until it reaches the monomials curves, we see that lists sizes that are more than 144 elements will incur significant compute cost and significance to the programmer. That is, any performance gained by the approaches mentioned in this investigation for smaller list sizes will be insignificant to the programmer. The programmer will conclude that the performance of the `zip()` function to iterate print statements is similar to the other approaches.

## Conclusion

Notable performance can be gained from using the `zip()` function to iterate through two lists in parallel during `list` creation. When iterating through two lists in parallel to print out the elements of the two lists, the `zip()` function will yield similar performance as the `enumerate()` function, as to using a manual counter variable, as to using an index-list, and as to during the special scenario where the elements of one of the two lists (either `foo` or `bar`) may be used to index the other list.

## The Python 3.6 script that was used to investigate list creation.

```
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def test_zip( foo, bar ):
    store = []
    for f, b in zip(foo, bar):
        #print(f, b)
        store.append( (f, b) )

def test_enumerate( foo, bar ):
    store = []
    for n, f in enumerate( foo ):
        #print(f, bar[n])
        store.append( (f, bar[n]) )

def test_count( foo, bar ):
    store = []
    count = 0
    for f in foo:
        #print(f, bar[count])
        store.append( (f, bar[count]) )
        count += 1

def test_indices( foo, bar, indices ):
    store = []
    for i in indices:
        #print(foo[i], bar[i])
        store.append( (foo[i], bar[i]) )

def test_existing_list_indices( foo, bar ):
    store = []
    for f in foo:
        #print(f, bar[f])
        store.append( (f, bar[f]) )


list_sizes = [ 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 ]
tz = []
te = []
tc = []
ti = []
tii= []

tcz = []
tce = []
tci = []
tcii= []

for a in list_sizes:
    foo = [ i for i in range(a) ]
    bar = [ i for i in range(a) ]
    indices = [ i for i in range(a) ]
    reps = 1000

    tz.append( timeit.timeit( 'test_zip( foo, bar )',
                              'from __main__ import test_zip, foo, bar',
                              number=reps
                              )
               )
    te.append( timeit.timeit( 'test_enumerate( foo, bar )',
                              'from __main__ import test_enumerate, foo, bar',
                              number=reps
                              )
               )
    tc.append( timeit.timeit( 'test_count( foo, bar )',
                              'from __main__ import test_count, foo, bar',
                              number=reps
                              )
               )
    ti.append( timeit.timeit( 'test_indices( foo, bar, indices )',
                              'from __main__ import test_indices, foo, bar, indices',
                              number=reps
                              )
               )
    tii.append( timeit.timeit( 'test_existing_list_indices( foo, bar )',
                               'from __main__ import test_existing_list_indices, foo, bar',
                               number=reps
                               )
                )

    tcz.append( timeit.timeit( '[(f, b) for f, b in zip(foo, bar)]',
                               'from __main__ import foo, bar',
                               number=reps
                               )
                )
    tce.append( timeit.timeit( '[(f, bar[n]) for n, f in enumerate( foo )]',
                               'from __main__ import foo, bar',
                               number=reps
                               )
                )
    tci.append( timeit.timeit( '[(foo[i], bar[i]) for i in indices ]',
                               'from __main__ import foo, bar, indices',
                               number=reps
                               )
                )
    tcii.append( timeit.timeit( '[(f, bar[f]) for f in foo ]',
                                'from __main__ import foo, bar',
                                number=reps
                                )
                 )

print( f'te  = {te}' )
print( f'ti  = {ti}' )
print( f'tii = {tii}' )
print( f'tc  = {tc}' )
print( f'tz  = {tz}' )

print( f'tce  = {te}' )
print( f'tci  = {ti}' )
print( f'tcii = {tii}' )
print( f'tcz  = {tz}' )

fig, ax = plt.subplots( 2, 2 )
ax[0,0].plot( list_sizes, te, label='enumerate()', marker='.' )
ax[0,0].plot( list_sizes, ti, label='index-list', marker='.' )
ax[0,0].plot( list_sizes, tii, label='element of foo', marker='.' )
ax[0,0].plot( list_sizes, tc, label='count()', marker='.' )
ax[0,0].plot( list_sizes, tz, label='zip()', marker='.')
ax[0,0].set_xscale('log')
ax[0,0].set_yscale('log')
ax[0,0].set_xlabel('List Size')
ax[0,0].set_ylabel('Time (s)')
ax[0,0].legend()
ax[0,0].grid( b=True, which='major', axis='both')
ax[0,0].grid( b=True, which='minor', axis='both')

ax[0,1].plot( list_sizes, np.array(te)/np.array(tz), label='enumerate()', marker='.' )
ax[0,1].plot( list_sizes, np.array(ti)/np.array(tz), label='index-list', marker='.' )
ax[0,1].plot( list_sizes, np.array(tii)/np.array(tz), label='element of foo', marker='.' )
ax[0,1].plot( list_sizes, np.array(tc)/np.array(tz), label='count()', marker='.' )
ax[0,1].set_xscale('log')
ax[0,1].set_xlabel('List Size')
ax[0,1].set_ylabel('Performances ( vs zip() function )')
ax[0,1].legend()
ax[0,1].grid( b=True, which='major', axis='both')
ax[0,1].grid( b=True, which='minor', axis='both')

ax[1,0].plot( list_sizes, tce, label='list comprehension using enumerate()',  marker='.')
ax[1,0].plot( list_sizes, tci, label='list comprehension using index-list()',  marker='.')
ax[1,0].plot( list_sizes, tcii, label='list comprehension using element of foo',  marker='.')
ax[1,0].plot( list_sizes, tcz, label='list comprehension using zip()',  marker='.')
ax[1,0].set_xscale('log')
ax[1,0].set_yscale('log')
ax[1,0].set_xlabel('List Size')
ax[1,0].set_ylabel('Time (s)')
ax[1,0].legend()
ax[1,0].grid( b=True, which='major', axis='both')
ax[1,0].grid( b=True, which='minor', axis='both')

ax[1,1].plot( list_sizes, np.array(tce)/np.array(tcz), label='enumerate()', marker='.' )
ax[1,1].plot( list_sizes, np.array(tci)/np.array(tcz), label='index-list', marker='.' )
ax[1,1].plot( list_sizes, np.array(tcii)/np.array(tcz), label='element of foo', marker='.' )
ax[1,1].set_xscale('log')
ax[1,1].set_xlabel('List Size')
ax[1,1].set_ylabel('Performances ( vs zip() function )')
ax[1,1].legend()
ax[1,1].grid( b=True, which='major', axis='both')
ax[1,1].grid( b=True, which='minor', axis='both')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 22):

You should use '[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip)' function. Here is an example how your own zip function can look like

```
def custom_zip(seq1, seq2):
    it1 = iter(seq1)
    it2 = iter(seq2)
    while True:
        yield next(it1), next(it2)
```

Comment: This is a pretty limited reinvention of `zip` and the wording is rather misleading. If you're going to reinvent the wheel (don't--it's a builtin function, not a dependency), at least [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60842028/6243352) accepts a variable number of iterables and generally behaves as you'd expect `zip` to.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do it with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (4, 5, 6)
[print('f:', i, '; b', j) for i, j in zip(a, b)]
```

It prints:

```
f: 1 ; b 4
f: 2 ; b 5
f: 3 ; b 6
```

Comment: [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)

Answer (score 5):

You can bundle the nth elements into a tuple or list using comprehension, then pass them out with a generator function.

```
def iterate_multi(*lists):
    for i in range(min(map(len,lists))):
        yield tuple(l[i] for l in lists)

for l1, l2, l3 in iterate_multi([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]):
    print(str(l1)+","+str(l2)+","+str(l3))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can just use an index to iterate...

```
foo = ['a', 'b', 'c']
bar = [10, 20, 30]
for indx, itm in enumerate(foo):
    print (foo[indx], bar[indx])
```

Comment: Why use `enumerate` if you're not actually using `itm`? Either change to `print(itm, bar[index])` or simply loop as `for indx in range(len(foo))`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep the indices while using `zip()` to iterate through multiple lists together, you can pass the `zip` object to `enumerate()`:

```py
for i, (f, b) in enumerate(zip(foo, bar)):
    # do something
```

e.g. if you want to print out the positions where the values differ in 2 lists, you can do so as follows.

```py
foo, bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'c']

for i, (f, b) in enumerate(zip(foo, bar)):
    if f != b:
        print(f"items at index {i} are different")
    
# items at index 1 are different
```

---

If your lists don't have the same length, then `zip()` iterates until the shortest list ends. If you want to iterate until the longest list ends, use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from the built-in `itertools` module. It pads the missing values by `None` by default (but you can change it to any value you want with the `fillvalue` parameter).

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
for f, b in zip_longest(foo, bar):
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is the old way.

```
import time

abc = list(range(10000000))
xyz = list(range(10000000))
start = time.time_ns()
for i in range(0, (len(abc)-1)):
    print("{} and {}".format(abc[i], xyz[i]))
print("Total time: {}".format(time.time_ns()-start))
```

Time: 12315440476ns

```
import time

abc = list(range(10000000))
xyz = list(range(10000000))
start = time.time_ns()
for a, b in zip(abc, xyz):
    print("{} and {}".format(a, b))
print("Total time: {}".format(time.time_ns()-start))
```

Time: 12338617143ns