# Inconsistency when I'm mapping lists into a dictionary using dict and zip - Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I tried this example and it worked fine: [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python/209854#209854)

But if I replaced "keys" with this list: 
['2', '3', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '2', '3', '2', '3', '4']

and "values" with this list: 
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

The dict class tried to make a dictionary of the "values" part alone!

OUTPUT:
{'3': 4, '2': 3, '4': 5}

Try it yourselves, you should get the same answer. A why and an alternative to this would be great.

Comment: The last values for your keys '2', '3', '4' are the last 3 values in your list - 3, 4, 5. Which is what your output has.. whats the issue ? what output were you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dict requires that there are no duplicate keys, but in your keys list you have lots of duplicates, so the dict will merge them. If you want to have multiple keys, you can use a multidict implementation to achieve that:

```
>>> a =  ['2', '3', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '2', '3', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b =  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> dict(zip(a, b))
{'3': 4, '2': 3, '4': 5}
>>> multidict.MultiDict(zip(a, b))
MultiDict([('2', 2), ('3', 3), ('2', 4), ('3', 5), ('4', 6), ('2', 4), ('4', 2),
 ('2', 1), ('2', 1), ('3', 2), ('2', 3), ('3', 4), ('4', 5)])
```

Note: I used `paste.util.multidict.MultiDict`, installabe by `pip install paste`.

Comment: Thanks for this, this was really what I was looking for. I think I was unfair to the other answerers because I should have specified that I wanted one key to point to a a lot of values.

Answer (score 7):

Your keys list has duplicate values and so overwrite the values from the earlier duplicate keys.

```
>>> keys = ['2', '3', '2-1', '3-1', '4', '2-2', '4-1', '2-3', '2-4', '3-2', '2-5', '3-3', '4-2']
>>> values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'2-2': 4, '4-1': 2, '4-2': 5, '2-1': 4, '2-4': 1, '2-3': 1, '2-5': 3, '3-3': 4, '3-2': 2, '3-1': 5, '3': 3, '2': 2, '4': 6}
```

Also, you can use integer keys for dictionaries just fine, so there's no need for the `'2'`, you can just use `2`.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary is a hash, which means each key can only exist once.

```
>>> a =  ['2', '3', '2', '3', '4', '2', '4', '2', '2', '3', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b =  [2,    3,   4,   5,   6,   4,   2,   1,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5 ]
>>> c = zip(a, b)
>>> c
[('2', 2), ('3', 3), ('2', 4), ('3', 5), ('4', 6), ('2', 4), ('4', 2), ('2', 1), ('2', 1), ('3', 2), ('2', 3), ('3', 4), ('4', 5)]
>>> dict(c)
{'3': 4, '2': 3, '4': 5}
```