# Map multiple lists of values to a list of keys in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to map some values(a list of lists) to some keys(a list) in a python dictionary.
I read [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

and figured I could do that this way :

```
headers = ['name', 'surname', 'city']
values = [
    ['charles', 'rooth', 'kentucky'], 
    ['william', 'jones', 'texas'], 
    ['john', 'frith', 'los angeles']
]
data = []

for entries in values:
    data.append(dict(itertools.izip(headers, entries)))
```

But I was just wondering is there is a nicer way to go?

Thanks

PS: I'm on python 2.6.7

Comment: how the output or expected result should look like is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already really nice...

```
data = [dict(itertools.izip(headers, entries) for entries in values]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
data = [dict(itertools.izip(headers, entries)) for entries in values]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import izip, imap
data = map(dict, imap(partial(izip, headers), values))
```

Comment: +1. If `values` has many items, this can be faster than the list comprehension I posted.