# Create dictionary from lists of keys and multiple values

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
header = ["Name", "Age"]
detail = ["Joe", 22, "Dave", 43, "Herb", 32]
```

And would like to create a list of dictonaries like this:

```
[{"Name": "Joe", "Age": 22}, {"Name": "Dave", "Age": 32}, {"Name": "Herb", "Age": 32}]
```

This method [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) gets me partially there, but only adds the first set of values to the dictionary:

```
>>> dict(zip(header, detail))
{'Age': 22, 'Name': 'Joe'}
```

How can I output as one dictionary for all values in the `detail` list? I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414090/map-multiple-lists-of-values-to-a-list-of-keys-in-a-python-dictionary), but this depends on `detail` containing nested lists.

Comment: Why do you need the `header` list? You're not using it for anything.

Comment: Updated expected output in question in to include `header` values. Sorry for the confusion :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such tasks I prefer functional approach.

Here is [a recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) for grouper:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

By using it, we may advance trough `detail` by groups of `2`:

```
>>> groups = grouper(len(header),detail)
>>> list(groups)
[('Joe', 22), ('Dave', 43), ('Herb', 32)]
```

And then we can use this iterator to create dictionaries as you need:

```
>>> [dict(zip(header,group)) for group in groups]
[{'Age': 22, 'Name': 'Joe'}, {'Age': 43, 'Name': 'Dave'}, {'Age': 32, 'Name': 'Herb'}]
```

To clarify, `zip(header,group)` gives this:

```
>>> zip(["Name", "Age"],('Joe', 22))
[('Name', 'Joe'), ('Age', 22)]
```

And summoning `dict` constructor gives this:

```
>>> dict([('Name', 'Joe'), ('Age', 22)])
{'Age': 22, 'Name': 'Joe'}
```

Comment: Might be better to use `len(header)` instead of `2` since you have it.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> detail = ["Joe", 22, "Dave", 43, "Herb", 32]
>>> d = dict(zip(detail[::2], detail[1::2]))
>>> d
{'Herb': 32, 'Dave': 43, 'Joe': 22}
```

For your new/edited question:

```
>>> d = [dict(zip(header, items)) for items in zip(detail[::2],detail[1::2])]
>>> d
[{'Age': 22, 'Name': 'Joe'}, {'Age': 43, 'Name': 'Dave'}, {'Age': 32, 'Name': 'H
erb'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get it:

```
header = ["Name", "Age"]
detail = ["Joe", 22, "Dave", 43, "Herb", 32]
data_iter = iter(detail)
collated = []
while True:
    next_data = zip(header, data_iter)
    if not next_data:
        break
    collated.append(dict(next_data))
```

output is

```
[{'Age': 22, 'Name': 'Joe'},
 {'Age': 43, 'Name': 'Dave'},
 {'Age': 32, 'Name': 'Herb'}]
```

This version has the advantage that you don't need to change the code if you change the number of headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> header = ["Name", "Age"]
>>> detail = ["Joe", 22, "Dave", 43, "Herb", 32]
>>> [dict(zip(header,detail[i:i+2])) for i in range(0,len(detail),2)]
[{'Age': 22, 'Name': 'Joe'}, {'Age': 43, 'Name': 'Dave'}, {'Age': 32, 'Name': 'Herb'}]`
```