# Populating dictionary values from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to construct a dictionary in python. Code looks like this:

```
dicti = {}
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
dicti = dicti.fromkeys(keys)

values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How can I populate values of dictionary using a list? Is there some built in function?

The result should be like this:

```
dicti = {1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5:6,6:7,7:8,8:9}
```

Comment: I want to add values from list, values=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: Please post what `dicti` should look like.

Comment: dicti={1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5:6,6:7,7:8,8:9}

Comment: @user1455966 You should use `dict.fromkeys` instead of using your dict's name to access that classmethod.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 26):

If you have two lists `keys` and the **corresponding** `values`:

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
dicti = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

`dicti` is now `{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9}`

Comment: As a note, one should be careful when using zip.  It is important to notice how `zip` drops values from the longer list.  This example demonstrates what would happen if someone intended to have 9 corresponding key:value pairs but missed the first value from the `values` list.  Notice how the values are actually shifted by one, e.g., value 2 ended up with key 1! This may not be the intended behavior.  Be sure to check that the code matches what you actually intended.

Answer (score 1):

Another one liner **for your specific case** would be:

```
dicti = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(values, start=1)}
```

The result is:

```
print(dicti)
{1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5:6,6:7,7:8,8:9}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work but the list have to be the same size (drop the 9 in the keys list)

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
values = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
dicti = {}

for x in range(len(keys)):
     dicti[keys[x]] = values[x]
```