# Convert two comma separated strings to Map

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I have two comma separated strings. I wish to put these values in map by binding values index by index. One way to do is using following example:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class StringToMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "1, 2, 3";
        String s2 = "a, b, c";
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();

        List<String> s1List = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s1.split(",")));
        List<String> s2List = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s2.split(",")));

        for (int i = 0; i < s1List.size(); i++) {
            m.put(s1List.get(i).trim(), s2List.get(i).trim());
        }

        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

Result is: {3=c, 2=b, 1=a}. Is there any other efficient/best way to do this?

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Comment: No need for the lists, just work on the arrays produced by  `split()`.

Comment: I think you'll have more information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418334/converting-string-arrays-into-map

Answer (score 1):

what do you think about this??

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "1, 2, 3";
    String s2 = "a, b, c";
    Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String s1List [] = s1.split(",");
    String s2List [] = s2.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < s1List.length && i < s2List.length; i++) {
        m.put(s1List[i].trim(), s2List[i].trim());
    }
    System.out.println(m);
}
```

Comment: I'd split outside the loop.

Comment: That's not very efficient.

Comment: @Thomas i have updated my answer according to your suggestion. thank you for improving my code.

Comment: @shmosel can you tell me where i can improve my answer?

Comment: @Abhishek, my issue was the same as Thomas. But I see you also forgot to `trim()`.

Comment: @shmosel i have updated my answer. thanks for your suggestion.