# Javascript converting 2 string arrays to map

Tags: javascript

I have two string arrays keys and values:

```html
let keys = [a,b,c,d]
let values = [1,2,3,4]
```

How to convert them into a map?

Expected output would be:

```
{a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4"}
```

Comment: Similar question made for Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418334/converting-string-arrays-into-map

Comment: @Pranay how you want the output?

Comment: You can start by writing some code.

Comment: What code have you tried already? What is your expected output? Do you want an actual JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or just a plain object? (Since those have keys/values as well).

Comment: Expected output would be: {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4"}

Comment: A "map", as you've shown it, is an object in JS.

Comment: Solved using one answer. Will accept answer in 1 min. 
(By the way, I don't understand why so much down-voting going on?) Obviously from the question you guys can understand java-script is not my choice of coding languages and thus comes the seemingly stupid questions..

Comment: @Pranay Questions get downvoted for not including things that are needed for people to be able to answer -- such as what your desired output/result is, example code, etc. Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to write good questions. People also tend to downvote if you don't show any attempt at solving the problem yourself, as SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use Map in ES6

```
var myMap = new Map();

// setting the values
myMap.set('key1', 'value1');
myMap.set('key2', 'value2');
myMap.set('key3', 'value3');
```

your answer :

```
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
     myMap.set(keys[i], values[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Come on, what is the point of downvoting an answer if you do not agree with the question?

Comment: @LoredraL It wasn't a good answer and it wasn't about not agreeing with the question. It was that the first attempt wasn't complete - it didn't generate the needed output based on the given inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly create an object. Then loop through your array and add the keys and values to the object.

```js
let keys = ['a','b','c','d'];
let values = [1,2,3,4];

let obj = {};

keys.forEach((key, index) => {
  obj[key] = values[index]
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: IMO `map` would be a better fit than `forEach`.

Comment: Why do you think that? :-)

Comment: Actually, I don't... changed my mind after thinking about it for a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use array reduce  on any of the array and use `index` to retrieve value from another array

```js
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let k = keys.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc[curr] = values[index]
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to declare your string arrays properly.

```js
let keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let values = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

var zip = (target, ...arr) => {
  if (target == null) throw Error('Target is undefined');
  if (arr[0] == null || arr[1] == null) throw Error('Lists must not be null');
  if (arr[0].length !== arr[1].length) throw Error('Lists must match in length');
  if (Array.isArray(target)) {
    arr[0].forEach((x, i) => target.push([arr[0][i], arr[1][i]]));
  } else if (typeof target === 'object') {
    arr[0].forEach((x, i) => target[arr[0][i]] = arr[1][i]);
  } else {
    throw Error('Unsupported target type');
  }
  return target;
}

var zipObj = (...arr) => zip.call(null, {}, ...arr);
var zipArr = (...arr) => zip.call(null, [], ...arr);

//console.log(zip({}, keys, values));
console.log(zipObj(keys, values)); // Zip object

//console.log(zip([], keys, values));
console.log(zipArr(keys, values)); // Zip array
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

When using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) this is a one-liner:

```
_.zipObject(keys,values)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
let keys = ['a','b','c','d']
let values = [1,2,3,4]
let mapped = keys.reduce((accumulator, current, index) => {
    accumulator[current] = values[index];
    return accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(mapped)
// Result should be:
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

Reduce is a powerful method that can be used for all sorts of tasks.

Here we're "reducing" the given values of `keys` into an object where `keys` are the key and `values` are the correlating values.

The first parameter in `reduce` is a callback function that you need to pass along at minimum `accumulator` and `current` variables (can have different names); the other parameters are `index` and `array` which represent the current index of the iteration and the original array that is being iterated.

The second parameter is the initial value of the `accumulator`; by default it will be the first `current` value but in our case we set it to `{}` so we can treat it as an object.

I hope this helps!