# Python. converting 2 lists into one dictionary object

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

I have 2 lists like this:
['one', 'two', 'three']
and
[1, 2, 3]

I want to turn it into a dictionary like this
{'one':1, 'two':2, 'three':3}

The catch is that i have to use comprehension.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to use comprehension?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, because "The catch is that I have to use comprehension". The accepted answer uses `dict(zip(keys, values))`; there is no answer that uses a list comprehension (although one answer uses a generator expression that could be turned into a comprehension with just two character changes.) That may be a stupid requirement, but it is a requirement, so it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 23):

```
keys=['one', 'two', 'three'] 
values= [1, 2, 3]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values)) 

>>> print dictionary
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

Take a look at [builtin functions](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip), they often become handy. You can use dict comprehensions from Python 2.7 up, but the they should not be the way to do it:

```
{k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
keys = ['one', 'two', 'three']
values = [1, 2, 3]
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

this is already the most pythonic way.

You can use a [dict comprehension](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays), if you really must:

```
{k: v for k,v in zip(keys, values)}
```

Comment: To be fair, the OP didn't say "list comprehension", so `d={k:v for k,v in zip(a, b)}` might qualify.  (Of course `dict(zip(keys, values))` is how I would do it too.)

Comment: @DSM Great point, added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

is probably the best way to do it. Don't use comprehensions, that's a silly requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you must:

```
keys = ['one', 'two', 'three']
values = [1,2,3]
d = {a:b for a,b in zip(keys,values)}
```

But seriously, just use `dict(zip(keys, values))`