# Converting two lists to a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I have two lists for example like this:

```
L = [1, 2]
S = ['B', 'C']
```

How can I get them to be combined into a dictionary like this:

```
X = {'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```

The lists will always be the same length, but can have any amount of items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: That output is not a list of dicts. It's just a dict

Comment: If one really wants to convert two lists into a list of dict, then `list_of_dict = [{'key1': L1, 'key2': L2} for (L1,L2) in zip(list_1,list_2)]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a one-liner:

```
dict(zip(S, L))
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
>>> key_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> value_list = [1, 2]
>>> result = dict(zip(key_list, value_list))
>>> print result
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> _
```