# how to create a dictionary using two lists in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
x = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
y = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,]]
```

I want to create a dictionary so the x and y values
would correspond like this:

```
1: [1,0], 2: [2,0]
```

and etc

Comment: Is this homework?  We users of SO charge at least $400/hr for homework, with prices subject to user.

Answer (score 36):

You can use zip function:
`dict(zip(x, y))`

```
>>> x = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
... y = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,]]
>>> dict(zip(x, y))
0: {'1': [1, 0], '2': [2, 0], '3': [3, 0], '4': [4]}
```

Answer (score 7):

In python > 2.7 you can use dict comprehension:

```
>>> x = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> y = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,]]
>>> mydict = {key:value for key, value in zip(x,y)}
>>> mydict
{'1': [1, 0], '3': [3, 0], '2': [2, 0], '4': [4]}
>>>
```

Still the best answer has already been given

> dict(zip(x, y))

In python <= 2.7 you can use `itertools.izip` in case you work with big lists as `izip` returns an iterator. For small lists like yours, the use of `izip` would be overkilling. Note however that `itertools.izip` dissapeared in python 3. In python 3, the `zip` builtin already returns an iterator  and in consequence `izip` was not needed anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The quick and easy answer is `dict(zip(x,y))`, if you're ok with the keys being strings.  otherwise, use `dict(zip(map(int,x),y))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to accomplish this.

```
from itertools import izip
x = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
y = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,]]
dict(izip(x, y))
```

If your flavor of Python is 3.x, then you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.zip_longest) to do the same thing.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
x = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
y = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,]]
dict(zip_longest(x, y))
```

Comment: So what's wrong with izip?

Comment: I've already flagged this question as an exact duplicate, but I don't know why people have down-voted this answer. It's nearly identical to this highly *up*-voted [similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/209880/1988505).

Comment: probably that 'Simple is better than complex'

Comment: @WesleyBaugh good point. but note the answer was from 2008, five years ago. Dict comprehensions were included in py2.7, in 2010, and the dict(zip()) answer, that imho is the best,  got x5 more votes and is the one selected

Comment: @joaquin Using a dict comprehension doesn't change the fact that `izip` in py2.7 is still more memory efficient when dealing with large dictionaries. The down-vote tooltip says "This answer is not useful". The fact is, this answer is useful.

Comment: @WesleyBaugh ok I reverse my downvote. It is true that izip can be much faster than zip. Note that this is not the case anymore in py3k where itertools.izip disappeared and good old zip returns an iterator. Still in py27, as the OP was not asking about big lists, IMHO this answer should not be recommended.

Comment: @joaquin:  In Py3K there is `itertools.zip_longest` which does the same thing as `izip` (with an optional fill value).