# Obtain a dict from an array of keys and one array of values

Tags: python

Let's be concise:

```
keys = ['a', 'b']
values = [1, 2]
d = the_function_i_m_looking_for(keys, values)
# d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Can you put a name for the_function_i_m_looking_for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @GraemeStuart it's a duplicate indeed, I didn't found that one since I kept using the words "array" when python is about "list"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of many possible ways is:

```
{k: v for k, v in zip (keys, values) }
```

Another would be:

```
dict (zip (keys, values) )
```

Hence:

```
def the_function_you_are_looking_for (keys, values):
    return dict (zip (keys, values) )
```

Comment: First and most complete one. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using zip to make key: value pairs and pass them into dict()

```
dict(zip(keys, values))
```

I don't know of a function that does this in one go.

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) paired with the [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor.

```
keys = ['a', 'b']
values = [1, 2]

d = dict(zip(keys, values))

print(d)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

For large lists you may want to use [itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

If your key / value lists are different sizes [izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with a default value.