# Python: Associating Function Output to Strings, then Combining into Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of computer nodes called node_names, and I want to find the amount of free ram in each node, and store that in a second list. I then want to combine these lists into a dictionary.

I have:

```
for i in range(0, number_of_nodes):
    sys_output = [commands.getoutput('ssh %s \'free -m\'' % node_names[i])]
    free_memory = [x.split()[9] for x in sys_output]
    print free_memory
```

For 4 nodes, this returns `[mem1],[mem2],[mem3],[mem4]`.

How can I combine each memory value into a single list? I'm having difficulty assigning `free_memory` as a list instead of a string which is replaced after each loop iteration.

Once I have a memory list, I should be able to combine it with the node_names list to make a dictionary file and do any necessary sorting.

Comment: Where does `memout` come from? Should that be `sys_output`?

Comment: And what you want is `[mem1, mem2, mem3, mem4]`? As a list?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change the name when trying to slightly clarify the name. I want each mem in a list yes, so I can add it to the node names and have node_name:free_memory for all 4 nodes.

Comment: the you should take `free_memory` out and initialize it as an empty list `[]`. Then just add new items like this: `free_memory += [x.split()[9] for x in sys_output]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend just building the dictionary directly:

```
import commands

node_free_mem = {}

for n in node_names:
    sys_output = commands.getoutput("ssh %s 'free -m'" % n)
    free_memory = sys_output.split()[9]
    node_free_mem[n] = int(free_memory)
```

Here's code that does exactly what you asked: it builds a list, then uses the list to make a dictionary.  Discussion after the code.

```
import commands

def get_free_mem(node_name):
    sys_output = commands.getoutput('ssh %s \'free -m\'' % node_name)
    free_memory = sys_output.split()[9]
    return int(free_memory)

free_list = [get_free_mem(n) for n in node_names]
node_free_mem = dict(zip(node_names, free_list))
```

Note that in both code samples I simply iterate over the list of node names, rather than using a `range()` to get index numbers and indexing the list.  It's simplest and best in Python to just ask for what you want: you want the names, so ask for those.

I made a helper function for the code to get free memory.  Then a simple list comprehension builds a parallel list of free memory values.

The only tricky bit is building the dict.  This use of `zip()` is actually pretty common in Python and is discussed here:

[Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

For large lists in Python 2.x you might want to use `itertools.izip()` instead of the built-in `zip()`, but in Python 3.x you just use the built-in `zip()`.

EDIT: cleaned up the code; it should work now.

`commands.getoutput()` returns a string.  There is no need to package up the string inside a list, so I removed the square braces.  Then in turn there is no need for a list comprehension to get out the free_memory value; just split the string.  Now we have a simple string that may be passed to `int()` to convert to integer.

Comment: This is extremely helpful and much appreciated. I'm having only one issue at the line: node_free_mem[n] = int(free_memory)

"int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'"

Is there some other way to force these entries to be integers?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I should have tested the code.  I'll edit it to make it correct.