# Create dictionary from 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My task: I have 2 lists different size(1,2,3,4 and "qwe","asd","zxc" for example). How I can create dictionary with this lists with next condition: if count of keys more than values-  dict[key]=None. If count of values more-just inore it.
My code:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=["qwe","asd","zxc"]
dictx={}
for x in range(len(list1)):
if x>len(list2):
    dictx[list1[x]]=None
else:
    dictx[list1[x]]=list2[x]
```

But I catch error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in 
    dictx[list1[x]]=list2[x]
IndexError: list index out of range
Where I do mistake?Python 3.4
    Upd.It's work, but I try to understand where my mistake in this code. Anybody have thought?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a dictionary (dict) from separate lists of keys and values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-can-i-make-a-dictionary-dict-from-separate-lists-of-keys-and-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pad the value list with `None`s using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat), then zip the lists:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

d = dict(zip(list1, chain(list2, repeat(None))))
```

`repeat(None)` is an infinite iterator that yields `None` forever.

`chain(list2, repeat(None))` is an iterator that yields items from `list2`, then yields `None`s when `list2` runs out.

`zip(...)` returns a list of pairs of corresponding elements from `list1` and the padded `list2`. `zip` stops when any input runs out, so the input is as long as `list1`.

Finally, `dict(...)` takes the list of key-value pairs and makes a dict with those keys corresponding to those values.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) as follows:

```
import itertools
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=["qwe","asd","zxc"]
print ({l1:l2 for l1,l2 in itertools.izip_longest(list1,list2,fillvalue=None)})
```

EDIT:
In python 3:

```
import itertools
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=["qwe","asd","zxc"]
print ({l1:l2 for l1,l2 in itertools.zip_longest(list1,list2,fillvalue=None)})
```

Output:

```
{1: 'qwe', 2: 'asd', 3: 'zxc', 4: None}
```

Comment: @user3342929: this answer used Python 2: Add parentheses: `print({l1:l2 .. stuff .. })`, and change `izip` to `zip`.

Comment: @DSM : Thanks for your help...I tested in python 2.7...now, i have modified to compile in python 3

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'izip_longest'...What I do wrong?)Sorry, don't see about change.

Comment: @user3342929: as I said, you have to change `izip` to `zip` -- `izip_longest` was renamed `zip_longest` in Python 3.  Try `from itertools import zip_longest` and then `dict(zip_longest(list1, list2))`.

Comment: Thanks, now it work.But why I can't use my algorithm? Where mistake?

Comment: `izip_longest` looks nice at first, but it doesn't do the right thing when the value list is longer than the key list.

Comment: In this case, what will you expect when value is longer than key list?

Comment: Excess values should simply be ignored. This answer creates a spurious `None` key mapping to the last excess value.