# Mapping list - list as dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Not to be confused with [this question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python).

I have a list called `a = [2, 3, 4, 1]`

I have some function say func(), which is as follows:

```
def func(a):
    o = []
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        x=a[:]
        x[i],x[(i+1)%n] = x[(i+1)%n],x[i]
        o.append(x)
    return o
```

and func(a) produces another list as follows:

```
[[3, 2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2]]
```

Now I want to map the output list to the list from which it is generated. So, how to generate a dictionary in the following format:

```
a            : o

key          : value1, value2........last value

[2, 3, 4, 1] : [3, 2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Can't you just do: `{tuple(a): func(a)}`?  (Minor detail: you can't have a `list` as a key so I converted it into a `tuple` instead.)  The real question is why you want this, since all you have is a dictionary with one element – do you have multiple values of `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in a dictionary cannot be mutable type. You can have a tuple instead. That is

```
(2, 3, 4, 1) : [3, 2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

This can be done as

```
def func(a):
    o = []
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n):
        x=a[:]
        x[i],x[(i+1)%n] = x[(i+1)%n],x[i]
        o.append(x)
    return {tuple(a):o}
```

For example `func([2,3,4,1])` will now return

```
{(2, 3, 4, 1): [[3, 2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2]]}
```

Also note: according to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) :

> The only types of values not acceptable as keys are values containing
>   lists or dictionaries or other mutable types that are compared by
>   value rather than by object identity, the reason being that the
>   efficient implementation of dictionaries requires a key’s hash value
>   to remain constant

**POST COMMENT EDIT**

You can access the keys directly usin `[]` notation.

E.g:

```
l = [2,3,4,1]
a =  func(l)
print (a[tuple(l)])
```

This will print the list of values.

Or you can loop through the entire dictionary

```
for i in a.items():
     for j in i:
          print (j)
```

This will print

```
 [3, 2, 4, 1]
 [2, 4, 3, 1] 
 [2, 3, 1, 4]
 [1, 3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: So how to written the key now? Key in our case is tuple(o).? Banagalorean helping bangalorean :D

Comment: @Technopolice Now the key is `tuple(o)`. What do you mean by *writing to a key* ?

Comment: I want to retrieve the key from the newly formed dictionary. So how to retrieve it? Like for key, value in such_dictionary: print key  ... will throw an error

Comment: @Technopolice if you do `for key,value in some_dict.items()` it should work fine. Note that `for key in some_dict` works as well.

Comment: In this case type of key is tuple, you can convert to list. e.g
>>> list(func([2,3,4,1]).keys()[0])

Comment: @Technopolice You forgot that I'm a *Bengalurian* and not *Bangalorean* :P