# Make a list of dicts by iterating over two lists (list comprehensions)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The lists have the same number of elements, and the names are unique.
I wonder, how can I make a dict in one action.

This is my current code:

```
    fees = [fee for fee in fees]
    names = [name for name in names]
    mdict = [
        {'fees': fee[i], 'names': names[i]}
        for i, val in enumerate(fees)]
```

Comment: use zip() or zip_longest()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: What kind of objects are `fees` and `names` before the assignment in the first two lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` on both lists in a *list comprehension*:

```
mdict = [{'fees': f, 'names': n} for f, n in zip(fees, names)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = dict(zip(fees, names))
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean zip?

```
dict(zip(fees, names))
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this

```
{fees[i]:y[i] for i in range(len(fees))}
```

or more quite :

```
dict(zip(fees, names))
```