# python: How to pair separated dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
name_list=['Tomas', 'Mina', 'John', 'Amy']
gender_list=['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']
```

How to create a dictionary variable that contains name:gender pairs using the name_list and gender list?

I have to use 'for'

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `for`.

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to get a pairs of (key, value); then pass it to [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) to get a mapping of those pairs:

```
>>> name_list=['Tomas', 'Mina', 'John', 'Amy']
>>> gender_list=['Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']
>>> dict(zip(name_list, gender_list))
{'Amy': 'Female', 'Tomas': 'Male', 'John': 'Male', 'Mina': 'Female'}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {name: gender for name, gender in zip(name_list, gender_list)}
{'Amy': 'Female', 'Tomas': 'Male', 'John': 'Male', 'Mina': 'Female'}
```