# How in Python make a dictionary of two lists, one of which consists of functions, and another - strings?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to have the following dictionary `actions = {'1': c1, '2': c2, '3': c3}`

```
def c1():
    print 'c1'
def c2():
    print 'c2'
def c3():
    print 'c3'

commands1 = ['1', '2', '3']
commands2 = [c1, c2, c3]
actions = {}
```

What I tried:

```
for c1 in commands1:
    for c2 in commands2:
        actions = dict(zip(c1, c2))
```

But it gives an error `argument #2 must support iteration`

Comment: Just do `dict(zip(commands1, commands2))`.

Comment: `c2` at that point is a single command from the second list, which you cannot iterate over.

Comment: Also, that looping thing won't work as you overwrite the variable `actions` at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered here:
[Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

```
dict(zip(list_a, list _b))
```

Comment: Then please flag as a duplicate, rather than copying the answer across.

Comment: If it has already been answered, consider flagging to close as a duplicate.

Comment: OK, sorry, I will do this