# Python - Zip 2 lists into 1 dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I'm making some scrip with Python and having one small question.

I have 2 lists:

1. `['name', 'age', 'sex', 'addr', 'city']`
2. `['Jack   24   male   no23   NY', 'Jane   25   female   no24   NY', 'Dane   14   male   no14   NY']`

So I want to have:

```
dictofJack = {'name': 'Jack', 'age': '24', 'sex': 'male', 'addr': 'no23', 'city':'NY'}

dictofJane = {'name': 'Jane', 'age': '25', 'sex': 'female', 'addr': 'no24', 'city':'NY'}

dictofDane = {'name': 'Dane', 'age': '14', 'sex': 'male', 'addr': 'no14', 'city':'NY'}
```

In this case, how can I use zip to make it get the dictionaries automatically in a for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Do you want a list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> header = ['name', 'age', 'sex', 'addr', 'city']
>>> values = ['Jack   24   male   no23   NY',
              'Jane   25   female   no24   NY',
              'Dane   14   male   no14   NY']
>>> dictofJack, dictofJane, dictofDane = (
        dict(zip(header, value.split())) for value in values
    )
>>> dictofJack
{'addr': 'no23', 'age': '24', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jack', 'sex': 'male'}
>>> dictofJane
{'addr': 'no24', 'age': '25', 'city':'NY', 'name': 'Jane', 'sex': 'female'}
>>> dictofDane
{'addr': 'no14', 'age': '14', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Dane', 'sex': 'male'}
```

BTW, instead of making multiple variables of dictionaries, I recommend to use dictionary of dictionaries (think of case where 100 of dictionaries required), using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> {value.split()[0]: dict(zip(header, value.split())) for value in values}
{'Jane': {'addr': 'no24', 'age': '25', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jane', 'sex': 'female'},
 'Dane': {'addr': 'no14', 'age': '14', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Dane', 'sex': 'male'},
 'Jack': {'addr': 'no23', 'age': '24', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jack', 'sex': 'male'}}
```

Comment: How about the case when 2 people have the same name?

Comment: I have this case:

header = ['name', 'age', 'sex', 'addr', 'city']
values = ['Jack   24   male   no23   NY',
          'Jane   25   female   no24   NY',
          'Jane   14   male   no14   NY']
print {value.split()[0]: dict(zip(header, value.split())) for value in values}

It will print like this:

{'Jane': {'addr': 'no14', 'age': '14', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jane', 'sex': 'male'}, 'Jack': {'addr': 'no23', 'age': '24', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jack', 'sex': 'male'}}

So how can we resolve this?

Comment: @ThắngPhạmNgọc,  How about using list of dictionaries: `[dict(zip(header, value.split())) for value in values`]`?

Comment: it will give back a list of multiple dict like this:

[{'addr': 'no23', 'age': '24', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jack', 'sex': 'male'}, {'addr': 'no24', 'age': '25', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jane', 'sex': 'female'}, {'addr': 'no14', 'age': '14', 'city': 'NY', 'name': 'Jane', 'sex': 'male'}]

it works, now I will try to split that list into multiple dict.
Thank you.