# how can i map one list with keys and others lists with values into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to make a dictionary which contains sub-dictionaries

```
K = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']  # key list
A = [['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], ['1', '2', '3']]  #value list
list_dict = ['dict1', 'dict2']
D = {d : {} for d in list_dict}
```

I want to do this:

```
D = {'dict1': {'k1': 'v1',
               'k2': 'v2',
               'k3': 'v3'},
     'dict2': {'k1': '1',
               'k2': '2',
               'k3': '3'}}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  You seem to be wanting someone to write your code for you, and that's not what we do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix zip function with a dict as follow:

```
K = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']  # key list
A = [['v1', 'v2', 'v3'], ['1', '2', '3']]  # value list
list_dict = ['dict1', 'dict2']
D = {}

for i in range(len(A)):
    D[list_dict[i]] = (dict(zip(K, A[i])))

print(D)
```

NB : it's very similar to : [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Thank you. This does the job too.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [70]: D = {d : dict(zip(K,v)) for d,v in zip(list_dict, A)}

In [71]: D
Out[71]: 
{'dict1': {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'},
 'dict2': {'k1': '1', 'k2': '2', 'k3': '3'}}
```

Comment: @omri_saadon Nah, that's what makes this *bad*. Should just use `dict(zip(K,v))` instead of `dict(zip(k,v))` with `k` repeatedly set to `K`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: damn good catch! Why didn't I think of that?!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
answer = {list_dict[l]: {K[i]: A[l][i] for i in range(len(K))} for l in range(len(list_dict))}
```

This sets answer to a dictionary where the keys are all the items in list_dict. The values are then dictionaries generated by using every item in K mapped to the corresponding item in A[l] where l is the number of the key in list_dict.

answer is:

```
{
'dict1': 
    {'k3': 'v3',
     'k2': 'v2',
     'k1': 'v1'},
'dict2': 
    {'k3': '3',
     'k2': '2',
     'k1': '1'}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
d = dict.fromkeys(list_dict)
for i, k in enumerate(sorted(d.keys())) :
    d[k] = {key:value for key, value in zip(K, A[i])}
```