# Can't merge two lists into a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, list, dictionary, python-itertools

I can't merge two lists into a dictionary.I tried the following :

[Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

I tried all solutions and I still get an empty dictionary

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from itertools import izip
import itertools

text_file = open("/home/vesko_/evnt_classification/bag_of_words", "r")
text_fiel2 = open("/home/vesko_/evnt_classification/sdas", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split('\n')
words = text_fiel2.read().split('\n')


diction = dict(itertools.izip(words,lines))
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(words, lines)}
print new_dict
```

I get the following :

{'word': ''}
['word=']

The two lists are not empty.

I'm using python2.7

EDIT :

Output from the two lists (I'm only showing a few because it's a vector with 11k features)

```
//lines
['change', 'I/O', 'fcnet2', 'ifconfig',....
//words
['word', 'word', 'word', .....
```

EDIT :

Now at least I have some output @DamianLattenero

```
{'word\n': 'XXAMSDB35:XXAMSDB35_NGCEAC_DAT_L_Drivei\n'}
['word\n=XXAMSDB35:XXAMSDB35_NGCEAC_DAT_L_Drivei\n']
```

Comment: Print out what `lines` and `words` is to make sure that worked ok

Comment: You have extra imports not needed too. `DictVectorizer` isn't used in this example, and probably `itertools` isn't required either as shown in answer below

Comment: @MrJLP That's correct, the problem should be in the loading of the data

Comment: For clarity I'd remove `itertools`, `DictVectorizer` imports and `diction` assignment as it's not relevant to the example

Comment: Use this `new_dict = dict(zip(words,lines))`. The answer below has it, but for the variable `diction` which isn't being printed out

Comment: How are the words in the file? like a stack? one obove other? or like a consecutive list? one aside the other?

Comment: Have you tried doing it the "C" way? `dict = {}`, `i = 0` `while i < len(lines):`, `dict[lines[i]] = words[i]`, `i += 1`. Does this have the expected output?

Comment: It's a text file with each word in a separate line.

Comment: If you're getting output like above the original problem has been solved. Having newline `\n` on each item is a different problem

Comment: That's right, I added you an observation in the anwer, Consider that a professional courtesy (John wick 2 :P)

Comment: @MrJLP with the exception that I have only 1 value for the key...so the dictionary is not full.

Answer (score 1):

I think the root of a lot of confusion is code in the example that is not relevant.

Try this:

```
text_file = open("/home/vesko_/evnt_classification/bag_of_words", "r")
text_fiel2 = open("/home/vesko_/evnt_classification/sdas", "r")
lines = text_file.read().split('\n')
words = text_fiel2.read().split('\n')

# to remove any extra newline or whitespace from what was read in
map(lambda line: line.rstrip(), lines)
map(lambda word: word.rstrip(), words)

new_dict = dict(zip(words,lines))
print new_dict
```

Python builtin `zip()` returns an iterable of tuples from each of the arguments. Giving this iterable of tuples to the `dict()` object constructor creates a dictionary where each of the items in `words` is the key and items in `lines` is the corresponding value.

Also note that if the `words` file has more items than `lines` then there will either keys with empty values. If `lines` has items then only the last one will be added with an `None` key.

Comment: I agree, that should work, if not, there are a problem with the paths or something. Plus one for clarity

Comment: What happened? What was the output?

Comment: I added something to strip the newline in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this and worked for me, I created two files, added numbers 1 to 4, letters a to d, and the code creates the dictionary ok, I didn't need to import itertools, actually there is an extra line not needed:

```
lines = [1,2,3,4]
words = ["a","b","c","d"]


diction = dict(zip(words,lines))
# new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(words, lines)}
print(diction)
```

> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

If that worked, and not the other, you must have a problem in loading the list, try loading like this:

```
def create_list_from_file(file):
  with open(file, "r") as ins:
    my_list = []
    for line in ins:
      my_list.append(line)
    return my_list

lines = create_list_from_file("/home/vesko_/evnt_classification/bag_of_words")
words = create_list_from_file("/home/vesko_/evnt_classification/sdas")

diction = dict(zip(words,lines))
# new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(words, lines)}
print(diction)
```

> Observation:
>   If you files.txt looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
```

and

```
a
b
c
d
```

the result will have for keys in the dictionary, one per line:

```
{'a\n': '1\n', 'b\n': '2\n', 'c\n': '3\n', 'd': '4'}
```

But if you file looks like:

```
1 2 3 4
```

and

```
a b c d
```

the result will be `{'a b c d': '1 2 3 4'}`, only one value

Comment: For some strange reason this doesn't work in my case @DamianLattenero

Comment: @VeselinIvanov even with those two testing lists? Because if those list works for you and do the job, the problem is when you load the wanted lists from the files... did you tried with those values from the list?

Comment: @VeselinIvanov I updated the answer, let me know if that work for you, there is no need to import anything

Comment: @DamianLattenero with the example lists it works , but unfortunately I can't do it manually, so I need to figure out why merging the two lists like in the other answers in stackoverflow didn't work me.

Comment: @VeselinIvanov Did you try load the list like that? I updated

Comment: I updated my question.Yes this time I atleast have something, but it's still only with lenght 1.As far as I see it took the last element only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145909/discussion-between-damian-lattenero-and-veselin-ivanov).