# How to build index map with multiple value from list in python with elegant way?

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

I want to build a dict in python from a list, the key of the dict is the first column and the value of the map is the second column. Is there any elegant way to implement this?

For example,

`A= [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]`

The result is

`M={1:[2,3],2:[3]}`

My own way is 

`for row in A:
    if row[0] not in M: M[row[0]] = []
    M[row[0]].append(row[1])`

Is there any better solution? Functional Programming methods are preferred.

Comment: Use the zip function.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

A= [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in A:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setdefault`:

```
A= [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
M = {}                                                                 
for k,v in A:
    M.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

M 
# {1: [2, 3], 2: [3]}
```

If it must be functional (Disclaimer: wasteful, not recommended):

```
import operator, itertools
grps = itertools.groupby(sorted(A, key=operator.itemgetter(0)), operator.itemgetter(0))
M = {k: list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), v)) for k, v in grps}
M
# {1: [2, 3], 2: [3]}
```