# How to add keys and values to dictionary from lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary with these keys `2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017` and these values `1, 123, 8765, 0987, 182735, 3459, 9, 0, 2 ,835, 874`

I already put these values and keys into lists, a list for each.

```
year = [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
value = [1, 123, 8765, 0987, 182735, 3459, 9, 0, 2 ,835, 874]
```

I want a diccionary that has key 2007 value 1 , 2008 123 and so.

I've tried `dic[key]=value` but it didn't work,
i've tried function fromkeys but it didn't work either. please help!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`dic[key] = value` must work provided the `key` and `value` are placed in a loop. A simple way to combine keys and values from two lists is using the [`zip` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
dct = dict(zip(year, value))
```

You can also use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
dct = {y: v for y, v in zip(year, value)}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> dict(zip(year, value))
{2007: 1, 2008: 123, 2009: 8765, 2010: 987, 2011: 182735, 2012: 3459, 2013: 9, 2014: 0, 2015: 2, 2016: 835, 2017: 874}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
year = [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017]
value = [1, 123, 8765, 987, 182735, 3459, 9, 0, 2 ,835, 874]

s = dict(zip(year, value))
print(s)
```