# Convert a list of tuples to dictionary, giving each tuple a different key

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples consisting of x,y coordinates ordered in a specific way and want to convert this to a dictionary, where each tuple has a different key.

How should I do this? If names is not doable, numbers would be fine as well.
Eventually the goal is to plot all the different points as categories.

```
# list of tuples
ordered_points = [(1188.0, 751.0),(1000.0, 961.0),(984.0, 816.0),(896.0, 707.0),(802.0, 634.0),(684.0, 702.0),(620.0, 769.0)]


# what I want 
orderder_points_dict = {'pointing finger':(1188.0, 751.0), 'middle finger':(1000.0, 961.0) etc...}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/map-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: from where you are picking `keys`?

Comment: I see 7 entries, I have 5 fingers. What should I do for the last two keys?

Comment: @akashkarothiya I want to insert them myself

Comment: @OlivierMelançon it includes some other coordinates as well. Could be anything, I havent decided on names yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested, in having just numbers as index, you can use `enumerate` to do this

```
>>> ordered_points = [(1188.0, 751.0),(1000.0, 961.0),(984.0, 816.0),(896.0, 707.0),(802.0, 634.0),(684.0, 702.0),(620.0, 769.0)]
>>> 
>>> dict(enumerate(ordered_points))
{0: (1188.0, 751.0), 1: (1000.0, 961.0), 2: (984.0, 816.0), 3: (896.0, 707.0), 4: (802.0, 634.0), 5: (684.0, 702.0), 6: (620.0, 769.0)}
```

Or if you have the keys in a seperate list,

```
>>> keys
['key0', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4', 'key5', 'key6']
>>> 
>>> dict(zip(keys,ordered_points))
{'key0': (1188.0, 751.0), 'key1': (1000.0, 961.0), 'key2': (984.0, 816.0), 'key3': (896.0, 707.0), 'key4': (802.0, 634.0), 'key5': (684.0, 702.0), 'key6': (620.0, 769.0)}
>>>
```

Comment: I want to point out that there is absolutely no advantage to having keys which are the index the item had in the list. The second part of the answer is the same as mine, so if you remove the first part of yours, I'll delete mine and upvote

Answer (score 2):

Given a list of keys correctly ordered, you can use `zip` to create your `dict`.

```
ordered_points = [(1188.0, 751.0), (1000.0, 961.0), ...]
keys = ['pointing finger', 'middle finger', ...]

d = dict(zip(keys, ordered_points))
# d: {'pointing finger': (1188.0, 751.0), 'middle finger': (1000.0, 961.0), ...: ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`:

```
expected_dict = dict(zip([i for i in range(len(ordered_points))],ordered_points))
```

Output:'

```
{0: (1188.0, 751.0), 1: (1000.0, 961.0), 2: (984.0, 816.0), 3: (896.0, 707.0), 4: (802.0, 634.0), 5: (684.0, 702.0), 6: (620.0, 769.0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of names:

```
ordered_points = [(1188.0, 751.0),(1000.0, 961.0)]
names = ['pointing finger', 'middle finger']
mydict = {}
for count, x in enumerate(names):
    mydict[x] = ordered_points[count]
```