# How to populate dictionary using loop

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I have two lists named `res_list` and `fina_list`. I want the first member of the `res_list` as key and first member of `fina_list` as the value and so on. Both the list are of the same length. I have written following code but I am not getting the answer please help me on this.

```
for i in range(0, len(prot_temp)):
    dict_dist[res_list_count[i]] = fina_val[i]
print (dict_dist)
```

res_list = ['LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS'] and fina_val = [['90', 30.390685694798005], ['91', 33.017900690383094], ['99', 25.200985952934463], ['104', 19.14776281971343], ['113', 20.365273138359818], ['114', 21.71637709195528], ['135', 29.452559922696025], ['138', 24.335606731700775]] but when I am doing as you said I am geeing fillowing answer: {'LYS': ['302', 25.757180610462783], 'ARG': ['282', 17.118237438474793]} where i am wrong ?

Comment: You probably want to rename your `fina_list` to `final_list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [`dictionary comprehension`](https://www.google.com/search?q=dictionary%20comprehension).

```
d = {k:v for k,v in zip(res_list, fina_list)}
```

Also, as [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084416/peter-wood) pointed out, one can do `dict(zip(res_list, fina_list)`!

---

Some more explicit (and perhaps less `Python(ic)` ways)

You can iterate over the zip to be more explicit.

```
d = {}
for k,v in zip(res_list, fina_list):
    d[k] = v
```

Of you can even iterate over the lists together with an index.

```
d = {}
for i in range(min(len(res_list), len(fina_list)):
    d[res_list[i]] = fina_list[i]
```

if those are more clear to you. However, part of the beauty of python is it's *conciseness* while maintaining *clarity*.

Comment: Or just use the [**`dict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor, which can take tuple pairs: `dict(zip(keys, values))`

Comment: @PeterWood That would be an exact duplicate though. See comment section.

Comment: @scharette a comprehensive answer can mention more than one method. Also, the answer wasn't there when I commented.

Comment: @PeterWood No, you missunderstood me. Your insight was really good. It was actually the best to acheive this. My point was that there is an exact duplicate that I inlcuded in the comments section.

Answer (score 2):

`dict`'s constructor accepts a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs, 
so you can achieve it with

```
dict(zip(res_list, fina_list))
```

Comment: res_list = ['LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'ARG', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS', 'LYS'] and fina_val = [['90', 30.390685694798005], ['91', 33.017900690383094], ['99', 25.200985952934463], ['104', 19.14776281971343], ['113', 20.365273138359818], ['114', 21.71637709195528], ['135', 29.452559922696025], ['138', 24.335606731700775]] but when I am doing as you said I am geeing fillowing answer: {'LYS': ['302', 25.757180610462783], 'ARG': ['282', 17.118237438474793]} where i am wrong ?

Comment: Since you have duplicated in res_list you need to decide on a proper way to handle it. A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys (for obvious reasons)

Comment: OOPS than what I could do ?

Comment: You can either aggregate values with the same keys in a list or rename your keys to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Please, update your question with those sample `res_list` and `fina_val`, since it is a major point