# Convert list of lists to list of dictionaries based on order of items in sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to convert my list of lists to list of dictionaries. Values of first list should be my keys and remaining all should be treated as values.

For example:

```
[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

should convert to

```
[{'a':[1,4,7]}, {'b': [2,5,8]},{'b': [3,6,9]}]
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python) but it did n't help for me..

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `zip` to transpose your array into `[('a', 1, 4, 7), ...]`; pop off the first element as key, listify the rest as value.

```
arr = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[{ e[0]: list(e[1:])} for e in zip(*arr)]
# => [{'a': [1, 4, 7]}, {'b': [2, 5, 8]}, {'c': [3, 6, 9]}]
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't notice, that's an unusual structure. OK... EDIT: fixed.

Comment: list of dicts is not so unusual though.

Comment: @ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ list of dicts, no. list of single key-value dicts is less usual than one dict, though. And I'm sleepy :P

Answer (score 4):

Using a list comprehension with sequence unpacking:

```
L = [['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

res = [{names: nums} for names, *nums in zip(*L)]

print(res)

[{'a': [1, 4, 7]}, {'b': [2, 5, 8]}, {'c': [3, 6, 9]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  
dictionary_values=[dict([(a[0][i],list(zip(*a[1:])[i])) for i in range (len(a)-1)])]
```

**output:**

```
[{'a': [1, 4, 7], 'b': [2, 5, 8], 'c': [3, 6, 9]}]
```