# Is there a faster alternative to dict(zip(list1,list2)) in python3?

Tags: python, dictionary, classification

Need to find a faster alternative to python's dict(zip(list1,list2))

I'm using dict(zip(list1,list2)) in a script for random forest classification which creates a dictionary from two lists. This takes about 0.002 seconds per execution. However its too slow for bulk prediction(when it needs to be executed 80K+ times)

```
for inp in listOfInputs[:]:
    pp = clf.predict_proba(inp)[0]  # clf is the classifier
    probaDict = dict(zip(clf.classes_,pp))
```

This loop takes 0.6 seconds if len(listOfInputs)=290 which is slow.
I need an efficient alternative for use with large bulk inputs for which  len(listOfInputs)=80,000+

Comment: Please check this out. Seems to be already happended exhaustive discussion on this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: Yes, I've seen that page but i'm using the fastest technique from them. Still isn't efficient enough! Need another way

Comment: Why are you making a copy of `listOfInput`? `for int in listOfInputs`. You need to confirm that the call to `dict` is actually your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess classes are fixed? So try re-using the same dictionary and change the key values istead of constructing a new dict every iteration