# Problem combining two tuples into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of sorted integer IDs like

```
[1, 2, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 34, ...]
```

I have a tuple (tuple1) of tuples of codes next to an ID sorted by ID like

```
((1, "A"), (2, "A"), (15, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"), ...)
```

I have another tuple (tuple2) of tuples in the same format like

```
((1, "B"), (2, "B"), (10, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"), ...)
```

I want to combine the tuples into a dictionary whereby the key is the ID and the value is a list containing their code from tuple1 and their code from tuple2 in that order. If the ID exists in the ID list but not in the tuple then the value should be `"N/A"`.

Therefore, using the above data the following should be produced:

```
{1: ["A", "B"], 2: ["A", "B"], 10: ["N/A", "B"], 15: ["B", "N/A"],
 16: ["A", "A"], 17: ["B", "B"], 20: ["N/A", "N/A"], 34: ["B", "B"]}
```

I have spent quite a while thinking about this problem but I cannot come up with a solution. If someone could help me figure out how to get it working in Python then that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks.

EDIT: **It is not a duplicate**, this problem is considerably more complex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @JordanSinger I believe it is more complex than that.

Comment: @JordanSinger Please read the question.

Comment: Are your tuples/lists huge (looking for a fast solution) or do you just need _some_ solution?

Comment: @JackP are all of your lists sorted by ID like they are in your question?

Comment: @StephenCowley They're not huge but they are about 400-2000 in size each, so a reasonably fast solution would be appreciated.

Comment: @wpercy Yes they are.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you make your tuple of tuples into a dictionary, it will be a lot easier. Use `get` to set a default value for your dictionary if the key is absent:

```
ids = [1, 2, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 34]
tup1 = ((1, "A"), (2, "A"), (15, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))
tup2 = ((1, "B"), (2, "B"), (10, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))

tup1 = dict(tup1)
tup2 = dict(tup2)    
{k: [tup1.get(k, 'N/A'), tup2.get(k, 'N/A')] for k in ids}
```

Comment: I assume you meant `tup1 = (1, "A"), (2, "A"), (15, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B")`, `tup1 = dict((x, y) for x, y in tup1)`. However, I still get the error "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'getitem'".

Comment: @JackP I mistakenly used `getitem` when I first posted. It should be `get`.

Comment: And I did mean to create a dictionary from the tuples. It allows you to use `get` and assign a default value: `'N/A'`.

Comment: It works without the extra list comprehension dict expression now you've added the extra parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear. I clarified my intention in the code regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one possible solution to this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

keys = [1, 2, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 34]

t1 = ((1, "A"), (2, "A"), (15, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))
t2 = ((1, "B"), (2, "B"), (10, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))

merge_d = defaultdict(list)
for d in map(dict, (t1, t2)):
    for k in keys:
        merge_d[k].append(d.get(k, "N/A"))
```

The resulting dict will contain:

```py
>>> merge_d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: ['A', 'B'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 10: ['N/A', 'B'], 15: ['B', 'N/A'], 16: ['A', 'A'], 17: ['B', 'B'], 20: ['N/A', 'N/A'], 34: ['B', 'B']})
```

Comment: Thank you but I think it is a bit slower than busybear's solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little gross, but you can do it without converting to a dictionary:

```
myList = [1, 2, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 34]
tuples1 = ((1, "A"), (2, "A"), (15, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))
tuples2 = ((1, "B"), (2, "B"), (10, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))

myDict = {} 

for i in myList:
    myDict[i] = ["N/A","N/A"] 

for t in tuples1: 
    if(t[0]) in myList:
        for key in myDict:
            if key == t[0]:
                myDict[key][0] = t[1]

for t in tuples2: 
    if(t[0]) in myList:
        for key in myDict:
            if key == t[0]:
                myDict[key][1] = t[1]

print(myDict)
```

Gives:

> {1: ['A', 'B'], 2: ['A', 'B'], 10: ['N/A', 'B'], 15: ['B', 'N/A'], 16: ['A', 'A'], 17: ['B', 'B'], 20: ['N/A', 'N/A'], 34: ['B', 'B']}

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if I wasn't clear but the ID should only be present in the final dictionary if it is present in the given list of IDs.

Comment: @JackP No problem. I'll update the answer, you just use the elements in the list instead of a generator.

Comment: Ah yes that seems to have worked thanks. Although I think it is a bit slower than busybear's solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done another way!

```
lis=[1, 2, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 34]
tuple1=((1, "A"), (2, "A"), (15, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))
tuple2=((1, "B"), (2, "B"), (10, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"))

z={**dict.fromkeys(lis,'N/A'), **dict(tuple1)}
y={**dict.fromkeys(lis, 'N/A'), **dict(tuple2)}    


ds = [z, y]
d = {}
for k in y.keys():
    d[k] = list(d[k] for d in ds)
```

Comment: Thank you but I think it is a bit slower than busybear's solution.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: a one-line solution, based on @busybear's answer, able to handle an arbitrary number of tuples:

```
ids = [1, 2, 10, 15, 16, 17, 20, 34]
vals = (
    ((1, "A"), (2, "A"), (15, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"),),
    ((1, "B"), (2, "B"), (10, "B"), (16, "A"), (17, "B"), (34, "B"),),
)

d = {i: [d.get(i, 'N/A') for d in map(dict, vals)] for i in ids}
```