# Append key,value to dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 different list. I want make them as a dict. But there is some prblem.As you see from code its key,value in list.How to make it to a  dict ealy?

I make key,value in list and idk how to convert to real dict one.
I share code for list one thanks a lot

I tried from dict but dict has no append. Imagine like a csv file. Header is column (8 column) , data is row (585 row)

```
for i in range(0,len(self.data)):
    for j in range(0,len(self.header)):
        self.output.append(self.header[j]+':'+self.data[i][j])
```

Comment: dict(zip(keys, values))                                possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python

Comment: It must be in loop its not clear way. And not as in code

Comment: In order to clarify the request it would help if you could provide sample input/output

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to build a dict from two lists:

```
>>> header = 'jan feb mar'.split()
>>> data = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(zip(header, data))
[('jan', 1), ('feb', 2), ('mar', 3)]
>>> dict(zip(header, data))
{'jan': 1, 'feb': 2, 'mar': 3}
```

EDIT

You updated the question to mention a CSV.
To produce a dict `d` like that you will need
to uniqueify with a row number `i`.

```
d = {f'{i:03d}-{hdr}': item
     for i, row in enumerate(data)
         for hdr, item in zip(header, row)}
```

Comment: here the biggest problem as you see from code header is duplicate. Len of header is 8 , len of data over 500.  Clearly ; Each data has 8 column and header is name of this column. But I dont know how to make like that. I tried with stupid idea like header=header*len(data) but dict(zip(header,data)) doesnt count duplicate I guess