# Explanation of dictionary creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am relatively new to Python, and I need some help to understand how the output is obtained for the following code:

```py
keys = ['id', 'name', 'age']
values = [10, 'Ross', 19]
a_dict = {key:value for key in keys for value in values}
print(a_dict)
```

The output is:

```
{'id': 19, 'name': 19, 'age': 19}
```

I have tried nested loop too and I got the same output. 
I also tried interchanging key and value in the loop but there was no effect.

Can someone explain this please?

**Edit:**

I know how to get the output as

```
{'id': 10, 'name': 'Ross', 'age': 19}
```

I am only requesting an explanation for how the code I wrote works.. especially how the for loop works for the value part.

Comment: What do you expect as output? Dictionary keys can't be duplicated.

Comment: Look at this:
[Convert 2 lists into dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert two lists into a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: I have come from that page only.. I just tried this out and it didn't work, so I asked it here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate simultaneously on both list, in order to pair the values with the keys:

```
keys = ['id', 'name', 'age']
values = [10, 'Ross', 19]
a_dict = {key:value for key, value in zip(keys, values)}
print(a_dict)
```

**output:**

```
{'id': 10, 'name': 'Ross', 'age': 19}
```

#### What is happening?

- `zip` pairs the keys and the values in a tuple `(key, value)`.
- then the pair is "unpacked" and assigned: `key, value = (key, value)`
- finally, the dictionary entry is built: `key: value`
- this is repeated for each pair in the input.

#### The code you wrote:

By comparison, the code you wrote `a_dict = {key:value for key in keys for value in values}` does:

- iterates over the keys.
- then, for each key, iterates over the values.
- for each key, assigns each value in succession, each time overwriting the values already assigned, and terminating with the last value assigned to all the keys, that is:
  `'id': 10, 'name': 10, 'age': 10'`
  `'id': 'Ross', 'name': 'Ross', 'age': 'Ross'`
  `'id': 19, 'name': 19, 'age': 19'`

Comment: And in that case it would be as simple as: `dict(zip(keys, values))`

Comment: Yes @AntonvBR, however, the most compact answer is not always conducive to explaining what is happening.

Comment: I know the result of using zip, I just wanted to understand how the code I wrote works..

Comment: You are welcome @a_faulty_star; I added a step by step explanation of what your code does.