# How to use for loop through two lists to create a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two lists as:

`num_list = [1,2,3,4]`

`name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]`

I want to create a new dictionary with `name_list` as keys and `num_list` as values. 
**I'm aware of** ***zip* method** but I'm trying to do it using `for` loop for my own learning . What I've tried as:

```
new={}
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]
for i in (name_list):
    for j in (num_list):
        new[i]=j
```

getting ouptput as:

`{'one': 4, 'two': 4, 'three': 4, 'four': 4}`

Can anyone explain where I did a mistake??

Comment: When you call the second for loop you are traversing through the entirety of `num_list` hence after your code executes, for each value in `name_list` gets assigned as a key-value pair with the last element of `num_list`, in this case `4`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15709950/8630546

Answer (score 2):

You're using nested for-loops.
For each `i` in `name_list`, and for each `j`  in `num_list`, you're adding one element in dictionary `new`. So, in the end, you're adding 4*4 = 16, key, value pairs into the dictionary.

You can do it in this way:

```
new={}
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]
for i in range(len(name_list)):
    new[name_list[i]]=num_list[i]
```

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15709950/8630546

Answer (score 0):

in second for loop for every key you are iterating over all values from num_list, because of that for each key you have last value(4) from num_list

you can just do:

```
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]

print (dict([[y,num_list[x]] for x,y in enumerate(name_list)]))
```

output:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
```

or:

```
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]

print ({name_list[i]:num_list[i] for i in range(len(num_list))})
```

output:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
```

If you want to use your code:

```
new={}
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]
for i in (name_list):
    for j in (num_list):
        new[i]=j
        num_list.remove(j) # <-----
        break # <-----

print (new)
```

output:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
```

NOTE: you are missing two lines of code

Comment: @ncica Thanks for explaining the error in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

To get an understand the error we have to dry-run your code. Let's do it, I copy-paste your original code here. Othewise you have to scroll screen.

```py
new={}
num_list = [1,2,3,4]
name_list = ["one","two","three","four"]
for i in (name_list):
    for j in (num_list):
        new[i]=j
```

**Dry-Run**

```sh
+-----+-----+-------------+
|  i  |  j  |   new[i]=j  |
+-----+-----+-------------+
| one |  1  |  {'one':1}  |
---------------------------
|     |  2  |  {'one':2}  |
---------------------------
|     |  3  |  {'one':3}  |
---------------------------
|     |  4  |  {'one':4}  |
---------------------------
```

I dry-run only for completing first round. So your 2nd for loop, looping 4 times. End of the 4th times your `j` value always `4`. That's why all the values in your dictionary became `4`. Can I suggest some easy-step? Your `num_list` and `name_list` both length is `4`. So try this if you want.

```py
for i in range(4):
    new[name_list[i]] = num_list[i]
print(new)

# or using dict comprehension

print({(name_list[i]): (num_list[i]) for i in range(4)})
```

**output:**

```sh
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4}
```