# Speed Test of Lambda Expression vs Local Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, time-complexity

I have two lists :

```
x = [ 0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 ]
y = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
```

I am merging these lists to get a dictionary like this :

```
z = {97: 'a', 98: 'b', 99: 'c', 100: 'd', 101: 'e', 102: 'f', 103: 'g', 104: 'h', 105: 'i', 106: 'j'}
```

I am completing this task with the help of `map` function.

It can be done in two ways :

**first way :**

```
z = map(lambda a,b : (a+97 , b), x, y)
```

**second way :**

```
def fun(a,b): return (a+97, b)
z = dict(map(fun, x, y))
```

**ANALYSIS :**

```py
import timeit

min(timeit.repeat(lambda:dict(map(lambda a,b:(a+97,b),x,y))))

def fun(a,b):
    return (a+97, b)

min(timeit.repeat(lambda:dict(map(fun, x, y))))
```

Above code is giving me the following output :

> 8.535995744000047
>
> 8.080758586999991

This code have a time difference of `0.45523715700005596 ms`. I have been informed that lambda expressions are same like inline functions those are used to increase the performance(execution speed).

**But according to above result it seems like this thought is a myth.
Is there any specific reason behind these weird time tests?
Are local functions with same content are faster then lambda expressions?**

I know the third way also to complete above task i.e.

```
z = dict([(k+97 , v) for k,v in zip(x, y)])
```

with `7.950903342999936 ms`,

But I am more interested in above test results.

Comment: Doesn't answer question, but I get pretty identical times for both @ ~4.6 us/loop-----%%timeit
z = dict(map(lambda a,b : (a+97 , b), x, y))=>100000 loops, best of 3: 4.64 µs per loop vs. %%timeit
def fun(a,b): return (a+97, b)
z = dict(map(fun, x, y))=>100000 loops, best of 3: 4.69 µs per loop

Comment: @DarrylG you are right it is a micro difference, but it is in wrong direction yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `min` is a terrible measure of performance as execution speed of any program is affected by other processes running on the machine. An average over a significant sample is far more informative

**Why the lambda is slower**

You are re-defining the lambda function on every iteration of timeit, if you were to assign the lambda to a variable and use it you would see that there is no significant difference

```
foo = lambda a, b: (a + 97, b)
min(timeit.repeat(lambda:dict(map(foo, x, y))))
```

Comment: May be you are right but better reason to use `min` instead of `mean` is provided by a user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737067/10180730)

Comment: Right redefining the lambda expression is time consuming. Your solution worked. Thanks