# Assign a label to each element of an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Hi So basically I got 2 arrays. For the sake of simplicity the following:

```
array_notepad = []
array_images = []
```

Some magic happens and they are populated, i.e. data is loaded, for `array_notepad` data is read from a notepad file whilst `array_images` is populated with the RGB values from a folder containing images.

How do I use `array_notepad` as a label of `array_images`?

i.e. the label of `array_images[0]` is `array_notepad[0]`, `array_images[1]` is `array_notepad[1]`, `array_images[1]` is `array_notepad[1]`, and so on until `array_images[999]` is `array_notepad[999]`

If it makes any difference I am using `glob` and `cv2` to read the image data, whilst normal python file reader to read the content in the notepad.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using dictionary for this?

Comment: You may need to be more specific with your terminology. The code you showed are initialized as two lists. Then you mentioned you wanted to add labels. Is array_images[] a `pandas` dataframe or tensor? Are are they literally lists that you want to insert a new column (`array_notepad` into `array_images`)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear on what your expected output should be. You mention 'label' - to me it sounds like you're describing key-value pairs i.e. a dictionary.

In which case you should be able to use the `zip` function as described in this question: [Convert two lists into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to create a dictionary from 2 lists. If so you could do as follows.

```py
array_notepad = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']
array_images = ['rgb1', 'rgb2', 'rgb3']

d = { label: value for label, value in zip(array_notepad, array_images) }
d
```