# How to break down a numpy array into a list and create a dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a following list and a numpy array :
 For the list :

```
features = np.array(X_train.columns).tolist() 

results :

['Attr1', 'Attr2', 'Attr3', 'Attr4', 'Attr5', 'Attr6', 'Attr7', 'Attr8', 'Attr9', 'Attr10', 'Attr11', 'Attr12', 'Attr13', 'Attr14', 'Attr15', 'Attr16', 'Attr17', 'Attr18', 'Attr19', 'Attr20', 'Attr21', 'Attr22', 'Attr23', 'Attr24', 'Attr25', 'Attr26', 'Attr27', 'Attr28', 'Attr29', 'Attr30', 'Attr31', 'Attr32', 'Attr33', 'Attr34', 'Attr35', 'Attr36', 'Attr37', 'Attr38', 'Attr39', 'Attr40', 'Attr41', 'Attr42', 'Attr43', 'Attr44', 'Attr45', 'Attr46', 'Attr47', 'Attr48', 'Attr49', 'Attr50', 'Attr51', 'Attr52', 'Attr53', 'Attr54', 'Attr55', 'Attr56', 'Attr57', 'Attr58', 'Attr59', 'Attr60', 'Attr61', 'Attr62', 'Attr63', 'Attr64']
```

and array name ab

```
aa=(lr.coef_) #I put a regression result on numpy array so I can split them, I want to put them as a list
ab=np.split(aa,len(aa))

results :

[array([[ 0.04181571,  0.62369216, -0.23559375,  0.78663624, -0.13935947,
        -0.1118698 , -0.05672835, -1.73851643, -0.42134655,  0.79001534,
         0.05048936, -0.09287526,  0.10103251, -0.0587092 , -0.05300849,
         0.72827807,  1.15870475, -0.13861187, -0.42572654,  0.19369654,
        -0.33319238, -0.06805035,  0.14067888, -0.07418516, -0.04400882,
        -0.78701564, -0.10921816, -0.26166642,  0.06800944,  0.07672145,
         0.22109349, -0.15389544,  2.41697614,  0.21749429, -0.0766771 ,
         0.77580103,  0.04128744, -0.92835969, -0.41802274,  0.89865658,
        -0.12102089, -0.28887104,  0.10421332,  0.14445757,  0.02719274,
        -1.73622976, -0.34980593,  0.35199196,  0.56110135,  0.4460968 ,
        -1.13265322,  0.26188587,  0.14336352,  0.2341355 , -0.10077637,
         0.43080231, -0.05521557, -0.1996818 ,  0.00513076, -0.14477274,
         0.04712721,  0.15380395, -2.51974007, -0.03988658]])]
```

Now, I want to make a dictionary for them but here I'm confused of how should I turn the array into list.

This is what I've done :

```
for x in features :
    for y in ab:
        print({x:y})

and the result is not as desired, since it's failed to break down the array :

{'Attr1': array([[ 0.04181571,  0.62369216, -0.23559375,  0.78663624, -0.13935947,
        -0.1118698 , -0.05672835, -1.73851643, -0.42134655,  0.79001534,
         0.05048936, -0.09287526,  0.10103251, -0.0587092 , -0.05300849,
         0.72827807,  1.15870475, -0.13861187, -0.42572654,  0.19369654,
        -0.33319238, -0.06805035,  0.14067888, -0.07418516, -0.04400882,
        -0.78701564, -0.10921816, -0.26166642,  0.06800944,  0.07672145,
         0.22109349, -0.15389544,  2.41697614,  0.21749429, -0.0766771 ,
         0.77580103,  0.04128744, -0.92835969, -0.41802274,  0.89865658,
        -0.12102089, -0.28887104,  0.10421332,  0.14445757,  0.02719274,
        -1.73622976, -0.34980593,  0.35199196,  0.56110135,  0.4460968 ,
        -1.13265322,  0.26188587,  0.14336352,  0.2341355 , -0.10077637,
         0.43080231, -0.05521557, -0.1996818 ,  0.00513076, -0.14477274,
         0.04712721,  0.15380395, -2.51974007, -0.03988658]])}
{'Attr2': array([[ 0.04181571,  0.62369216, -0.23559375,  0.78663624, -0.13935947,
        -0.1118698 , -0.05672835, -1.73851643, -0.42134655,  0.79001534,
         0.05048936, -0.09287526,  0.10103251, -0.0587092 , -0.05300849,
         0.72827807,  1.15870475, -0.13861187, -0.42572654,  0.19369654,
        -0.33319238, -0.06805035,  0.14067888, -0.07418516, -0.04400882,
        -0.78701564, -0.10921816, -0.26166642,  0.06800944,  0.07672145,
         0.22109349, -0.15389544,  2.41697614,  0.21749429, -0.0766771 ,
         0.77580103,  0.04128744, -0.92835969, -0.41802274,  0.89865658,
        -0.12102089, -0.28887104,  0.10421332,  0.14445757,  0.02719274,
        -1.73622976, -0.34980593,  0.35199196,  0.56110135,  0.4460968 ,
        -1.13265322,  0.26188587,  0.14336352,  0.2341355 , -0.10077637,
         0.43080231, -0.05521557, -0.1996818 ,  0.00513076, -0.14477274,
         0.04712721,  0.15380395, -2.51974007, -0.03988658]])}
{'Attr3': array([[ 0.04181571,  0.62369216, -0.23559375,  0.78663624, -0.13935947,
        -0.1118698 , -0.05672835, -1.73851643, -0.42134655,  0.79001534,
         0.05048936, -0.09287526,  0.10103251, -0.0587092 , -0.05300849,
         0.72827807,  1.15870475, -0.13861187, -0.42572654,  0.19369654,
        -0.33319238, -0.06805035,  0.14067888, -0.07418516, -0.04400882,
        -0.78701564, -0.10921816, -0.26166642,  0.06800944,  0.07672145,
         0.22109349, -0.15389544,  2.41697614,  0.21749429, -0.0766771 ,
         0.77580103,  0.04128744, -0.92835969, -0.41802274,  0.89865658,
        -0.12102089, -0.28887104,  0.10421332,  0.14445757,  0.02719274,
        -1.73622976, -0.34980593,  0.35199196,  0.56110135,  0.4460968 ,
        -1.13265322,  0.26188587,  0.14336352,  0.2341355 , -0.10077637,
         0.43080231, -0.05521557, -0.1996818 ,  0.00513076, -0.14477274,
         0.04712721,  0.15380395, -2.51974007, -0.03988658]])}.......
```

Could you help me to build a list for `ab` array?
And how should I turn them into dictionary?

```
Th expected results : {[Attr1 : 0.04181571],  Attr2 : 0.623692160, and so on...}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert two lists into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: `ab` is not just a list or array as you seem to think. It's a 1-element list containing an array, which is 2D. You just need to make `ab` be the first element of the list, or don't bother splitting maybe?

Comment: Your creation of `ab` is confusing.

Comment: This is the result that I got :{'Attr1': array([[ 0.04181571,  0.62369216, -0.23559375,  0.78663624, -0.13935947,
         -0.1118698 , -0.05672835, -1.73851643, -0.42134655,  0.79001534,
          0.05048936, -0.09287526,  0.10103251, -0.0587092 , -0.05300849,
          0.72827807,  1.15870475, -0.13861187, -0.42572654,  0.19369654,    do you know which part should be split again? because the elements of  ```ab``` is concentrated in as one and can't be split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the built-in function [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) :

```
dict(zip(features, ab[0].ravel()))
```

you can check the docs for [numpy.ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy.ravel)

> Return a contiguous flattened array.
>
> A 1-D array, containing the elements of the input, is returned.

---

since your `ab` variable is obtained with [numpy.split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy-split)  `ab` is a list with one numpy array as you showed

Comment: Sorry, but the result is similar with the instance above, any other solution perhaps?

Comment: why ? it is not working or ?could you share an error ?

Comment: This is the result that I got :{'Attr1': array([[ 0.04181571, 0.62369216, -0.23559375, 0.78663624, -0.13935947, -0.1118698 , -0.05672835, -1.73851643, -0.42134655, 0.79001534, 0.05048936, -0.09287526, 0.10103251, -0.0587092 , -0.05300849, 0.72827807, 1.15870475, -0.13861187, -0.42572654, 0.19369654, do you know which part is the problem? because the elements of ab is concentrated in as one and can't be split

Comment: @dhika91 check now my answer :)

Comment: Now it's working ! Thank you very much ! I should have realized it that the ```ab``` is 1D

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of making a dictionary from two lists:

```
In [277]: {k:v for k,v in zip(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])}                                                                
Out[277]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

In [278]: dict(zip(['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]))                                                                          
Out[278]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the result is similar with the instance above, any other solution perhaps?

Comment: Your loop created a list of dictionaries, one key each, and the same array as value.  We have showed you how to make one dictionary, with multiple keys. If you want one number per key, you need to flatten the `ab` list.  I don't think the `split` is doing anything for you.  Also check the shape of the array.  Looks like it will be (1,64), where as you want a 'flat' one, shape (64,).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
for x in features :
    for y in ab:
        print({x:y})
```

use

```
result = {}
for x, y in zip(features, ab) :
    result[x] = y
```

or — even simpler:

```
result = dict(zip(features, ab))
```

---

The explanation:

`zip(features, ab)` creates the generator of pairs `('Attr1', 0.04181571)`,  `('Attr2', 0.623692160)`, and so on, then we make directory from them.

Comment: Sorry, but the result is similar with the instance above, any other solution perhaps?

Comment: Use `ab[0]` instead of just `ab` in my solution(s). Or — perhaps — even `ab[0][0]`

Comment: This is the result that I got :{'Attr1': array([[ 0.04181571, 0.62369216, -0.23559375, 0.78663624, -0.13935947, -0.1118698 , -0.05672835, -1.73851643, -0.42134655, 0.79001534, 0.05048936, -0.09287526, 0.10103251, -0.0587092 , -0.05300849, 0.72827807, 1.15870475, -0.13861187, -0.42572654, 0.19369654, do you know which part is the problem? because the elements of ab is concentrated in as one and can't be split

Comment: Try my solution(s) with simply `aa` instead of `ab` (effectively omitting your command `ab=np.split(aa,len(aa))`).

Comment: Did you try my solution(s) with `ab[0][0]` instead of `ab`?