# Is there a way to make a dictionary from a single list where the key and value for the dict are taken from a specific index

Tags: python

After creating a list from a couple of text files I get the following :

```
['host : myhost.ro', 'port : 12222', 'service_name : SRVNM', 'user : MGA', 'password : Test']
```

Is there a way to make 2 lists like this :

```
lst1 =['host', 'port', 'service_name', 'user', 'password']
lst2 =['myhost.ro', '12222', 'SRVNM', 'MGA', 'Test']
```

Or to make a dictionary from the original list, this is my end goal, a dict like this :

```
Dict['host'] = 'myhost.ro'
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary) help?

Comment: You want a dict, definitly - "parallel lists" is an antipattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
data = ['host : myhost.ro', 'port : 12222', 'service_name : SRVNM', 'user : MGA', 'password : Test']

data_dict = dict([tuple(e.split(" : ")) for e in data])
print(data_dict)
```

Comment: Note that this is creating unnecessary temporary objects. A more memory efficient approach would be to drop the `list` comprehension and the `tuple` conversion: `dict(e.split(" : ") for e in data)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension:

```
lst = ['host : myhost.ro', 'port : 12222', 'service_name : SRVNM', 'user : MGA', 'password : Test']

dct = {key: value for item in lst for key, value in [item.split(" : ")]}
print(dct)
```

Which yields

```
{'host': 'myhost.ro', 'port': '12222', 'service_name': 'SRVNM', 'user': 'MGA', 'password': 'Test'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with some combination of `str.strip`, `str.split`, `map`, `zip`, comprehension generators:

```
# ...to obtain the `dict`
dict(map(str.strip, x.split(':')) for x in ll)
# {'host': 'myhost.ro', 'port': '12222', 'service_name': 'SRVNM', 'user': 'MGA', 'password': 'Test'}
```

```
# ...to obtain the "parallel" sequences (`tuples`)
l1, l2 = zip(*(map(str.strip, x.split(':')) for x in ll))
l1
# ('host', 'port', 'service_name', 'user', 'password')
l2
# ('myhost.ro', '12222', 'SRVNM', 'MGA', 'Test')
```

Assuming the input to be:

```
ll = ['host : myhost.ro', 'port : 12222', 'service_name : SRVNM', 'user : MGA', 'password : Test']
```

Also, it looks like the `dict()` seems a better option in this use case.

Comment: I don't yet got the 2 lists, I only got the first one, I'm yet to split the first list into 2 lists like that, i wish it was that simple

Comment: @MGA it is not that difficult either

Answer (score 0):

```
original = ['host : myhost.ro', 'port : 12222', 'service_name : SRVNM', 'user : MGA', 'password : Test']

b = dict([a.split(' : ') for a in original])
```

Comment: there are leftover whitespaces in keys and values

Comment: I fixed it by adding spaces in the split

Answer (score 0):

You can split your list into two lists that you want like this:

```
myList = ['host : myhost.ro', 'port : 12222', 'service_name : SRVNM', 'user : MGA', 'password : Test']
list1 = []
list2 = []

for i in myList:
    element1 = i.split(":")[0]
    element2 = i.split(":")[1]
    list1.append(element1)
    list2.append(element2)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
['host ', 'port ', 'service_name ', 'user ', 'password ']                                                             
[' myhost.ro', ' 12222', ' SRVNM', ' MGA', ' Test']
```

Or Your Final desired Dictionary will be  achieved by:

```
newDict = {}

for i in myList:
    key = i.split(":")[0].strip()
    value = i.split(":")[1].strip()
    newDict[key] = value
print(newDict)
```

Output:

```
{'user': 'MGA', 'port': '12222', 'service_name': 'SRVNM', 'password': 'Test', 'host': 'myhost.ro'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Take advantage of string method `split` and list \ dict comprehensions.

To get your dict:

```
data = ['host : myhost.ro', 'port : 12222', 'service_name : SRVNM', 'user : MGA', 'password : Test']
{entry.split(' : ')[0]:entry.split(' : ')[1] for entry in data}
```