# how to merge 2 lists in a specific way using python

Tags: python, list, set

I am learning python,

I am trying to merge keys['One', 'Two', 'Three'] and values [1, 2, 3] so I can get

a form of ==>: {'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}

but it's not working with me in the below code.

Plus what is the difference if it was a form of ==>: ['One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3] ?

please post the working code and explain how it works, try to make it works with long sets to.

```
keys = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
values = [1, 2, 3]

after=values.join(keys)

print(after)
```

Comment: `list` does not have a `.join()` method.

Comment: `['One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3]` What is this supposed to be? Do you want a `dict` maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert two lists into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: yes but not tottaly @faressalem

Answer (score 1):

For sets:

```
keys = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
values = [1, 2, 3]
after = set(zip(keys, values))
print(after)
```

Result: `{('One', 1), ('Three', 3), ('Two', 2)}`

For dicts:

```
keys = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
values = [1, 2, 3]
after = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(after)
```

Result: `{'One': 1, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3}`

Using the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function you can combine two lists and set one list as the key and another list as your values as you seem to want to do.

Answer (score 1):

`[ 'one' : 1, 'two' : 2 ]` this isn’t proper python syntax, if you want a list of key-value pairs, you need a list of tuples, like this `[('one',1), ('two',2)]`.