# Tuple into dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple like this

```
([(a,),(b,),...],[(x,),(y,),...])
```

I want to transform it into a dictionary like this:

```
sozluk={"a":x,"b":y,...}
```

I am looking for a practice way to realize that

Comment: There are something you need to declare:Do them have the same length?What have you tried?(`tuple[0]` and `tuple[1]`)

Comment: Are both the list equal in length?

Comment: seems like a straightforward dictionary comprehension using `zip` should work. Also -- are `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. already strings? If not, what are they? Something like `{s[0]:t[0] for s,t in zip(*tuples)}`

Comment: both are in the same length. the left side list is timestamp values as DateTime, right side list is actual values as the float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
t = ([(1,),(2,),(3,)],[('a',),('b',),('c',)])

r = {key[0]: value[0] for key, value, in zip(t[0],t[1])}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works also in Python2.7 and Python3 (I use ' to create string instead of variable, just for test):

```py
    q = ([('a',),('b',)],[('x',),('y',)])
    print({k[0]:v[0] for k,v in zip(*q)})

    {'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a simple `zip` should work, but in your case, each item is a tuple instead of a single element. So here, I use a simple [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python#:~:text=List%20Comprehensions,kinds%20of%20objects%20in%20lists.) to convert the tuple into keys and values, and then create the dictionary based on those with a simple `zip` ([more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)):

```py
>>> t = ([("a",),("b",)], [("x",),("y",)])
>>> keys = [i[0] for i in t[0]]
>>> keys
['a', 'b']
>>> values = [i[0] for i in t[1]]
>>> values
['x', 'y']
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'a': 'x', 'b': 'y'}
```