# How to combine two lists using lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda, dictionary-comprehension

I have two lists

```
names = ['Bruce', 'Clark', 'Peter', 'Logan', 'Wade']
heroes = ['Batman', 'Superman', 'Spiderman', 'Wolverine', 'Deadpool']
```

From these lists, I want a dict of {'name': 'hero'} for each name,hero using a lambda function. Here's my desired output:

```
{'Bruce': 'Batman', 'Clark': 'Superman', 'Peter': 'Spiderman', 'Logan': 'Wolverine', 'Wade': 'Deadpool'}
```

I have the code below that works but when I try to put it together using a lambda function I don't get as expected. Here is the code that works using dictionary comprehensions

```
dc_dict = {name: hero for name, hero in zip(names, heroes)}
print(dc_dict)
```

I am trying to replicate the above logic using lambda function and that doesn't work as expected. Here is what I have come up with.

```
l_dict = dict(lambda names[name]:heroes[hero] for (name, hero) in zip(names, heroes))
print(l_dict)
```

TIA

Comment: You could use : `dict(zip(names, heroes))` that'll be easier. Why use a `lambda`?

Comment: You just don't need a lambda here, but it should generate a tuple with two items because dict expects an iterable of such tuples. The code in parentheses in the last example is a generator expression (similar to dict comprehension) which doesn't need lambda ib this case.

Comment: What was the `lambda` supposed to do?  You aren't calling it, and `dict()` doesn't know to call it.

Comment: yeah, just trying to challenge myself to see if I can put it together using a lambda.

Comment: `name: hero` and `names[name]: heroes[hero]`.

Comment: Lambdas in Python are a way to define functions without naming (hence storing) them - not sure that it could prove useful here. Most efficient will be using Python natives (`dict(zip())`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

> just trying to challenge myself to see if I can put it together using
>   a lambda

Since we've established that the `lambda` isn't necessary, if not down right undesirable, let's do it:

```
names = ['Bruce', 'Clark', 'Peter', 'Logan', 'Wade']
heroes = ['Batman', 'Superman', 'Spiderman', 'Wolverine', 'Deadpool']

l_dict = dict((lambda n, h: {name: hero for name, hero in zip(n, h)})(names, heroes))
print(l_dict)
```

The problem is you can't pass a `lambda` expression to `dict()`, only the result of invoking a `lambda` expression.

Comment: Good to know about this. Thanks cdlane