# Python - create dictionary from two lists with repeated elements

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

Trying to use zip() to create a dictionary from two lists (keys and values) where there is a repeated key element. What I want is for the dictionary to have a single key for the repeated element and for the corresponding value to be the sum of the repeated values.

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b']
lst2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_dictionary = dict(zip(lst1,lst2))
print(new_dictionary)
```

Actual output: `{'a': 2, 'b': 6, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}`

Desired output: `{'a': 2, 'b': 9, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert two lists into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `defaultdict` you can set the type to `int`. This will let you simply add to it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dictionary = defaultdict(int)

lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b']
lst2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for k, n in zip(lst1,lst2):
    new_dictionary[k] += n
    
print(new_dictionary)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a': 2, 'b': 9, 'c': 4, 'd': 5})
```

You could also use `collections.Counter()` the same way by simply using `new_dictionary = Counter()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```py
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b']
lst2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new_dictionary = {}

for key, value in zip(lst1, lst2):
    if key in new_dictionary:
        new_dictionary[key] += value
    else:
        new_dictionary[key] = value

print(new_dictionary)
```