# Creating a list of dictionary from two unique list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to create a list of dictionary in the form

```
my_var = [{'a': 'jack','b': 120}, {'a':'davis', 'b': 150}]
```

The two lists that I want to use to create the dictionary

```
j = ['jack', 'davis'] and d = [120, 150]
```

I need help in creating the dictionary `my_var`, how can I do this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert two lists into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
j = ['jack', 'davis'] 
d = [120, 150] 
my_var  = [dict(zip(('a', 'b'), (j[i], d[i]))) for i  in range(min(len(j), len(d)))]
```