# Dictionary - How to map list of KEY with list of VALUE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two different list:

```
key = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']
value = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

I want to map it like this :

```
dictionary = {'key1':'value1',
              'key2':'value2',
              'key3':'value3'}
```

I tried this:

```
dictionary = {key, value}
```

But I got this result:

```
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

Comment: Please search on stack overflow before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this to get the desired result,

```
dictionary = dict(zip(key, value))
```

Comment: Using `zip` is a good way of preserving the order of key, value items from the lists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
dictionary = {key[i]:value[i] for i in range(len (key))}
```

This is what is called a dictionary comprehension.

Essentially what you are doing is looping through the indexes
and accessing the various values at the dictionary.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension) might help

Answer (score 0):

```
res = {key[i]: value[i] for i in range(len(key))}
```