# Adding a 2D array to a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a list and a 2D array

example:

```
key = ['a', 'b', 'c']
value = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
```

Using this I need to create a dictionary with key as list items and values as list in 2D array.

expected dictionary is:

```
dicts = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b': [4,5], 'c': [6,7,8,9]}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: It's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/209854/7076819). Just do: `dict(zip(key, value))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
key = ['a', 'b', 'c']
value = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9]]

res = dict(zip(key, value))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do `dictionary = dict(zip(key, value))`, however if youd like to see how it its done with for loop have a look.

```
key = ['a', 'b', 'c']
value = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
res={}
for i in range(len(key)):
    res[key[i]] = value[i]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following

```
key = ['a', 'b', 'c']
value = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8,9]]
```

A quick and easy solution is as follows:

```
a_dictionary={}

for i in range(len(key)):
    a_dictionary[key[i]]=value[i]
```