# How to iterate through an array and a list of tuples making a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

In python how would you iterate through a list (column names) and a list of tuples (row values) in order to build a list of dictionaries? The keys always being generated from the first array and the values generated from each tuple?

```
col = ['id', 'username', 'email']
rows = [('1234', 'first', 'first@email.com'), ('5678', 'second', 'second@email.com')]

result = [{'id':'1234', 'username':'first', 'email':'first@email.com'},{'id':'5678', 'username':'second', 'email':'second@email.com'}]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
[dict(zip(col, row)) for row in rows]
```

How this works:

- The `[... for row in rows]` part loops through the `rows` list to construct a new list.
- `zip(col, row)` matches up corresponding items of `col` and `row`, so we end up with `[('id', '1234'), ('username', 'first'), ...]`
- Finally, `dict(...)` converts the list of tuples into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
col = ['id', 'username', 'email']
rows = [('1234', 'first', 'first@email.com'), ('5678', 'second', 'second@email.com')]

result = [dict(zip(col, i)) for i in rows]
```

gives

```
[{'id': '1234', 'username': 'first', 'email': 'first@email.com'}, {'id': '5678', 'username': 'second', 'email': 'second@email.com'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zip()` function:

```
[in]: 
col = ['id', 'username', 'email']
rows = [('1234', 'first', 'first@email.com'), ('5678', 'second', 'second@email.com')]
result = [dict(zip(col, r)) for r in rows]


[out]: 
[{'id': '1234', 'username': 'first', 'email': 'first@email.com'}, {'id': '5678', 'username': 'second', 'email': 'second@email.com'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you expecting:

```
result = []
for i,rowsv in enumerate(rows):
  row_num=0
  for colv in col:
    if(row_num==0):
      result.append("{"+colv+":"+rowsv[row_num])
    elif(row_num== len(col)-1):
      result.append(colv+":"+rowsv[row_num]+"}")
    else:
      result.append(colv+":"+rowsv[row_num])
    row_num+=1
print(result)
```

output:

```
['{id:1234', 'username:first', 'email:first@email.com}', '{id:5678', 'username:second', 'email:second@email.com}']
```