# Transform multiple lists to dictionary of tuples

Tags: python

I'm attempting to convert multiple lists into a dictionary where the initial list contains the keys.

For example:

```
list_keys = ['a' , 'b']
list_vals_1 = ['tick' , 'tack']
list_vals_2 = ['big' , 'small']
```

is transformed into:

```
expected = {}
expected['a'] = ('tick' , 'big')
expected['b'] = ('tack', 'small')
print('expected' , expected)
```

I could transform the lists using into a dictionary using:

```
mappings = {}
i = 0
for l in list_keys :
    mappings[l] = (list_vals_1[i] , list_vals_2[i])
    i = i + 1
```

Is there a cleaner/better solution using Python to accomplish this ?

Comment: Related: [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209840/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `zip`

```py
dict(zip(list_keys, zip(list_vals_1, list_vals_2)))
```

```
{'a': ('tick', 'big'), 'b': ('tack', 'small')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> {k: (v1, v2) for k, v1, v2 in zip(list_keys, list_vals_1, list_vals_2)}
{'a': ('tick', 'big'), 'b': ('tack', 'small')}
```

---

Also, for what it's worth, you could have used [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to improve your existing solution:

```
for i, k in enumerate(list_keys):
    mappings[k] = (list_vals_1[i], list_vals_2[i])
```

---

By the way, note that [`l` is a bad variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) since it looks like `1` and `I`. I used `k` instead - short for "key".