# How to zip into dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Zip the gender and category into dictionary

```
gender ={ 'Male','Female','Transgender'}
category={'boy','girl','boy_and_girl'}
updated_list = dict(zip(gender,category))
print(updated_list)
```

Expected output:

```
{'Male': 'boy_and_girl', 'Transgender': 'girl', 'Female': 'boy'}
```

Comment: Already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gender and category should be lists, not sets, as sets are not sorted data structures. Try:

```
gender =[ 'Male','Female','Transgender']
category=['boy','girl','boy_and_girl']
updated_list = dict(zip(gender,category))
print(updated_list)
```

Comment: Tq tino for answering my question.