# Python: How can loop over two lists one for key and one for value and place that into a new empty dictionary?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

Here is the data I have I want to loop over the two lists the symbol list as the key and symbol_name as the value
how do I do it with using the loop

```
calculator_dict = {}   # the new dictionary i want to put both the list into

symbols = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

symbol_name = ["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"]

for symbol in symbols:

  for name in symbol_name:

    calculator_dict[symbol] = name

print(calculator_dict)
```

What i want to be printed is:

```
calculator_dict = {
    "+": "add",
    "-": "subtract",
    "*": "multiply",
    "/": "divide",
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `zip` and `dict` functions:

```
>>> symbols = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
>>> symbol_name = ["add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"]
>>> dict(zip(symbols, symbol_name))
{'+': 'add', '-': 'subtract', '*': 'multiply', '/': 'divide'}
```