# Why are the values in my dictionary not following my range() values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some code:

```
dict = {i:j for i in range(1,10,2) for j in range(10,2,-2)}

print(dict)
```

The output that I get is: `{1: 4, 3: 4, 5: 4, 7: 4, 9: 4}`

The output that I am expecting is: `{1:10,3:8,5:6,7:4,9:2}`

While I agree with the keys, what is happening to the values? Why are they stuck at 4? Because when I do range(10,2,-2) this produces 10,8,6,4,2

I have also tried:

```
dict= {}

for i in range(1,10,2):
    for j in range(10,2,-2):
        dict[i] = j

print(dict)
```

But yield the same result. Any ideas why? It must be my range() function.

Comment: it seems to have something to do with your second for loop's "step"

Comment: Note: This has nothing to do with your question. Please don't use ```dict``` as a variable name.

Comment: yea don't use dict as a variable name because `dict` is a `type`

Comment: Also ```range(10,2,-2)``` only gives ```10,8,6,4``` and not ```10,8,6,4,2``` as you've stated. ```range(start, end)``` only includes the ```start``` value and excludes the ```end``` value.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? Perhaps you want `{i: j for i, j in zip(range(1,10,2), range(10, 2, -2)}` instead.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], meaning, add your expected output. You can [edit]. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have edited the question to include the desired result, any ideas how to obtain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are all 4 because for each key in the outer loop, all the values in the inner loop are assigned, overwriting each time until the final value, which is 4.

You can get the result you want by zipping two `range`s together.

```py
>>> xp = {1:10,3:8,5:6,7:4,9:2}
>>> expected = {1:10,3:8,5:6,7:4,9:2}
>>> d = dict(zip(range(1, 10, 2), range(10, 0, -2)))
>>> expected == d
True
```

Note that the descending `range` goes from 10 to 0: 10 to 2 will not generate enough elements:

```py
>>> list(range(10, 2, -2))
[10, 8, 6, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution snake. One question, I do understand zip(), but I fail to see how "d = dict(zip(range(1, 10, 2), range(10, 0, -2)))" is creating key/value pairs in the dictionary. Because normally we would have something like d[key] = value. what does dict(argument) do? Because I tried to run it on my IDE and can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Or is dict(zip(...)) a well known thing?

Comment: `dict` will accept a sequence of key-value pairs and create a dictionary: `dict([('a', 1), ('b', 2)])` ->  `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`.  Using `zip` lets us create the key-value pairs from two sequences.  It's quite a common idiom - see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/209840/5320906) for more examples and techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Notice how you have two nested for loops:

```
dicti= {}

for i in range(1,10,2):
    for j in range(10,2,-2):
        dicti[i] = j

print(dicti)
```

The second for loop will loop through all values in `for j in range(10,2,-2):`
And since your `dicti[i]` gets re-assigned to the newest value, your `i`'s value will always be 4.

Comment: Your ```dict``` gives ```{1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8, 9:10}``` which I suppose is not what the OP asked.

Comment: i'm pretty sure thats what he asked tho @Ram

Comment: Nothing about his question suggests he wants a value that's just one greater than the key.

Comment: Remove the second half of your answer, and it's fine.

Comment: The above solution produces exactly the same output as mine did?

Comment: @patrickchong , you asked for why and not how. JSYK (just so you know)

Answer (score 1):

You have to nested for loops, but only need one loop with pairs of values.

The next problem is, that the stop value in `range` is exclusive

```
{i:j for i, j in zip(range(1,10,2), range(10,1,-2))}
```