# Struggling with a challenge

Tags: python

I was given two lists :

```
list1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F",1,"G",3,"H","I","J","K","L"]
list2 = [20 ,27 ,"Arm","Leg",13 ,24 ,"Head",75 ,64 ,71 ,"Ankle", 82 ,45 ,23 ]
```

Using the shortest code possible, I need to create a dictionary (`dictChallenge`) containing only the letter from `list1` and only the numbers from `list2`.

The output of `print(dictChallenge)` is:

```
{'A': 20, 'B': 27, 'E': 13, 'F': 24, 'G': 75, 'H': 71, 'J': 82, 'K': 45, 'L': 23 }
```

Comment: hmm, what have you tried?

Comment: hint: iterate through both lists at the same time (read about `zip`) and then go from there.

Comment: I think you mean, *how* I'm supposed to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: The challenge is obviously designed to get you to think about the subproblems within the problem, and it's obvious you haven't done that yet or your question would be more specific.

Comment: Would you please explain what do you mean by *shortest code possible*?

Comment: `C` is certainly a letter -- why isn't it in the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the two lists together and then filter that list based on your conditions. You can then use that list in a dict comprehension or pass it to `dict()`:

```
list1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F",1,"G",3,"H","I","J","K","L"]
list2 = [20 ,27 ,"Arm","Leg",13 ,24 ,"Head",75 ,64 ,71 ,"Ankle", 82 ,45 ,23 ]

{k: v for k, v in zip(list1, list2) if isinstance(k, str) and isinstance(v, int)}
```

Which gives you:

```
{'A': 20,
 'B': 27,
 'E': 13,
 'F': 24,
 'G': 75,
 'H': 71,
 'J': 82,
 'K': 45,
 'L': 23}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `zip` and `isinstance` to check if it is and integer or a string.

```
dict1={}
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    if isinstance(j,int) and isinstance(i,str):
        dict1[i]=j
print(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["A","B","C","D","E","F",1,"G",3,"H","I","J","K","L"]
list2 = [20 ,27 ,"Arm","Leg",13 ,24 ,"Head",75 ,64 ,71 ,"Ankle", 82 ,45 ,23 ]
keys = [L for L in list1 if type(L)==str]
values = [d for d in list2 if type(d) ==int]
DictChallenge = dict(zip(keys,values))
print(DictChallenge)
```