# building dictionary from list of column names and list of numbers with a for loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am simply trying to build a dictionary with keys from a list of strings and values that area list of numbers.

```
filepath = path
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=sheet)


columns = df.columns
fields = columns.to_list()
values = [1,2,3]
dict = {}

def build_dict(fields,values):
    for i in fields:
        dict[i] = fields[i]
    print(dict)

build_dict(fields,values)
```

I consistently end up with...
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: `fields` is a list of strings, so `i` is a string; the error is saying you can't do `fields[i]`

Comment: `for i in fields` already gives you the elements of `fields` in `i`. You can't do `fields[i]` again (unless `fields` is a list of integers and you really wanted to do this, but it's a list of strings)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: (1) You shouldn't name a variable `dict`: that's overriding the dict type. (2) What about `values` - you're doing nothing with it in the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary from two lists as follows:

```
filepath = path
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name=sheet)


columns = df.columns
fields = columns.to_list()
values = [1,2,3]
dict = dict(zip(fields, values))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since it's a pretty basic question, you should look to see if the same question has been asked already before adding an answer.