# Sort two simple lists alphabetically and from least to greatest, then merge them into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, merge

I have these lists:

```
aList = ['a','d','n','e','z']
numList=[1,14,5,26,4]
```

Output should be:

```
aDict = {'a':1, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'n':14, 'z':26}
```

My code was:

```
a = aList.sort()
b = bList.sort()

#merge both into a dict
```

Comment: And what was your failed approach? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert two lists into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209840/how-do-i-convert-two-lists-into-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:
`aList = ['a','d','n','e','z'] numList=[1,14,5,26,4]`

First Sort the lists:`aList.sort(),numList.sort()`

Then zip them:
`aDict = dict(zip(aList,numList))`

Answer (score 3):

Try using a dictionary comprehension:

```py
aDict = {key:value for key, value in zip(sorted(aList), sorted(numList))}
print(aDict)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'n': 14, 'z': 26}
```