# Create a nested dictionary in Python using nested lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have three lists:

```
A = ['a','b','c']
B = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
C = ['A','B']
```

And I need to create a dictionary with the following characteristics:

```
{'A':{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, 'B':{'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6}}
```

This is my code but it fails because the second loop only shows me the latest iteration.

**My code:**

```
{C[j]: {A[i]:B[j][i]} 
    for j in range(len(C))
        for i in range(len(A))}
```

**Output:**

```
{'A': {'c': 3},
 'B': {'c': 6}}
```

Any idea how to produce the desired dictionary?

Comment: Does this work? `{key: dict(zip(A, values)) for key, values in zip(C, B)}`

Comment: Try starting with a normal `for` loop instead of list/dictionary comprehension for something like this. I find it easier to work out nested logic in the classical form, and then translate it into comprehensions (if the result still human-readable).

Answer (score 1):

The command below gives the desired result:

```py
{c: dict(zip(A, b)) for b in B for c in C}
```

It is not recommended to use this syntax `range(len(C))` to loop over iterables in Python.

Refer to this answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/209854 for how the constructor `dict` works with the `zip` built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

I think below will help you.

```
{k : dict(zip(A, bs)) for k, bs in zip(C, B)}
```